# Definir a obrigatoriedade de campos na aplicação em vez do banco de dados é viável?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Me deparei com um sistema em que a maior parte das regras de obrigatoriedade de campos é feita na aplicação e não no banco de dados (com exceção da chave primária).

Como não tenho experiência com muitos sistemas, gostaria de saber se isso é comum e traz alguma vantagem ou se é inviável.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O melhor seria primeiramente garantir as Regras de Integridade (RIE e RIR) no próprio banco de dados, para manter a consistência deste. Isso garante que mesmo se a sua aplicação for alterada ou substituída, seus dados estarão protegidos e consistentes.

Quando o assunto são regras de negócio, muitos preferem inseri-las na aplicação.

Tem uma publicação muito interessante sobre esse assunto no seguinte link:

[A Arte do Software: Regras de negócio na aplicação](http://andrethiago.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/regras-de-negocio-devem-permanecer-na-aplicacao/)

Answer (score 4):

Esse é um assunto bem controverso, especialmente entre o pessoal que desenvolve software para web. Uns preferem deixar tudo na aplicação, outros dividir a responsabilidade.

Pessoalmente acredito que quanto menos "pontas soltas" você deixar melhor. Dessa forma, acredito que valha a pena, se sua aplicação for grande o suficiente, fazer a validação de consistência nas duas pontas.

A aplicação cuida da parte dela validando tudo o que é necessário antes de inserir no banco de dados (nunca confie nos dados que os usuários enviam) e o banco de dados mantém suas chaves estrangeiras e correlatos.

Como desenvolvedor, com alguma frequência quebro a consistência entre aplicação e banco quando trabalho sozinho num projeto. E tenho certeza de que as coisas tendem a quebrar mais quando mais pessoas trabalham juntas num projeto, ou mesmo quando mais de um projeto precisa acessar dados do mesmo banco de dados.

Comment: Falando exclusivamente de obrigatoriedade de campo não vejo o motivo de um NOT NULL ser motivo de discussão.

Comment: `NOT NULL` não é motivo de discussão nunca. se o campo é obrigatório, ele deve estar presente, se não é obrigatório, o campo não deveria nem estar na mesma tabela e e sim numa outra tabela auxiliar.

Answer (score 4):

Mantenha em ambos.

A coisa que mais vejo, atualmente, são sistemas onde as regras ficam apenas na aplicação, já que atualmente saber o mínimo de base de dados parece ser uma grande exigência.

O que acontece? No melhor dos cenários, onde apenas sua aplicação usa o banco: algum usuário vai lá diretamente no SGBD e apaga algum dado. Como não existe nem foreign_keys, pronto: agora os dados estão inconsistentes. E vejo isso com uma frequência assustadora.

No pior cenário, vários aplicativos terão acesso ao mesmo banco.

Então, no mínimo, mantenha também no banco os campos que são obrigatórios (definidos como `NOT NULL`), as chaves estrangeiras, e use restrições para valores, como o ENUM no MySQL (ou CHECK do Oracle) quando possível.

A validação (ao menos de campos obrigatórios) e constraints (como as foreign_keys) no banco são como cinto de segurança: você vai achar que nunca precisa deles, até que um acidente aconteça.

Answer (score 2):

Cara isso vai depender da sua necessidade, tanto de negócio quanto de consistência.

Haverá casos que você irá precisar garantir no banco de dados que o valor do campo não poder ser `null`, te darei um exemplo, você tem uma tabela **Produto** que se relaciona com **Plano**, nessa tabela **Produto** você tem o valor do produto, se no banco de dados você não deixar ele como obrigatório você poderá incluir um produto via `insert` no banco sem esse valor, mas se por exemplo, você fizer isso, e na camada de negócios da sua linguagem de programação que você estiver usando ser de fatal necessidade você ter esse valor pra vender algum **Plano** desse **Produto**, você começaria a ter uma falta de consistência muito grande nos seus dados a ponto de não ser possível realizar a venda.

Mas como a grande maioria dos fatores na área de desenvolvimento de software, deverá sempre haver uma analise, até quando você precisa desses dados concisos no DB e até quando não. Feito isso implemente da forma que você conclui melhor pra cada caso.

Answer (score 1):

Quando possível prefiro ter a garantia das *constraints* no BD, nem sempre é pois existem pacotes comercializados em diversos Bds e pode ficar inviável administrar Bds diferentes.

Gosto também de *Triggers* de validação de Regras de Negócio sendo que cabe as mesmas observações já ditas.