# Usar validação via cliente é suficiente?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validação, engenharia-de-software

Utilizar validações em JavaScript é suficiente para uma validação eficiente?

**Exemplo**: Validação de datas.

- É necessário verificar também no código?
- Quais as desvantagens de só realizar validações via *cliente-side* podem causar?

Comment: HTML e JavaScript pode ser alterado no navegador ou fiddlers.

Comment: Essa pergunta é muito semelhante a esta outra: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10657/definir-a-obrigatoriedade-de-campos-na-aplicacao-em-vez-do-banco-de-dados-e-viav/10692

Comment: Talvez você tenha esquecido de aceitar alguma delas, já que você costuma fazer. Nenhuma resposta foi satisfatória? Se for o caso, eu arriscaria uma nova resposta :)

Comment: @bigown Não esqueci, eu gostei das respostas mas creio que possa aparecer uma mais completa!

Comment: Mais uma semelhante: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16469/e-mais-sensato-usar-validacoes-no-lado-do-cliente-em-rails

Comment: Bem resumido: Na Intranet da empresa, valide do lado do cliente e registre log de ações.
Na Internet, valide tudo.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Vou considerar que o AP fala das validações que poderiam ser feitas exclusivamente no lado do cliente. Existem validações que são inerentemente impossíveis de serem feitas sem ajuda do servidor. São casos que dependem de informações que o cliente não tem e ou que a informação não esteja em estado definitivo.

## Web

Vou falar no uso da web embora as condições valham para qualquer tipo de cliente. Na web a validação no servidor é fundamental, já em outros tipos de clientes onde o código fonte não está disponível, onde você tem controle de quem tem acesso ao cliente e a rede é fechada essa necessidade não é tão importante assim. Claro que sempre poderá ter um risco em deixar a verificação só no cliente, mas é preciso entender o ambiente onde o sistema rodará, a cultura onde ele será utilizado. **Para tudo existem exceções**. Em alguns casos o risco devidamente avaliado e considerado baixo pode ser compensador. Ainda assim não é desejável que deixe todo controle no lado do cliente.

## Por que a validação deve ser no servidor?

Os principais motivos já foram ditos nas outras respostas, vou resumir:

- **Os dados que vêm do cliente nunca são confiáveis**, eles podem ser alterados/falsificados à revelia do código do seu cliente por mais que você tome algumas precauções para dificultar.
- Não há garantias que você poderá validar efetivamente em todas as situações. **Você não tem controle do ambiente onde seu cliente está rodando**.

Você pode ter problemas de:

- consistência de dados
- dados mal formados
- recepção de dados maliciosos
- exploração de falhas no sistema
- sobrecarga do servidor
- falhas não previstas
- coisas que ninguém previu ainda

Você tem que **validar tudo**, mesmo que use ferramentas prontas do *framework* para delegar essa validação. É comum o programador esquecer de validar algumas coisas. Por exemplo, ele valida a data entrada, mas esquece daquilo que não é óbvio que pode estar errado em alguma situação específica. Ele não pensa como o *hacker/cracker* que vai tentar fraudar seu sistema. Precisa validar se a informação não vai abrir buracos de segurança no sistema. Mas cuidado com as ferramentas que parecem validar bem mas só fazem algo superficial. Exemplo: `ValidateRequest` do ASP.NET (que não está disponível no .NET mais moderno). Ela não está errada, o erro é usá-la achando que ela resolve todos seus problemas.

## Validando só no cliente

**Você pode fazer uma validação só no cliente** se ela sozinha não importa para o sistema. Pode ser alguma coisa que sirva para facilitar a experiência da UI dando uma informação adicional para o usuário, mas que a informação não seja importante se está correta e principalmente se ela não é enviada para o servidor. Se a informação não será persistida e não irá influenciar em outras operações não há porque validar no lado do servidor. Mas isto é raro. Apenas é bom ter consciência disto para não adotar uma única solução cegamente.

## Validando só no servidor

Em alguns casos é preciso **questionar se deve realmente validar no lado do cliente**. Há casos que validar só no servidor pode ser a melhor escolha. Não quer dizer que você deve esperar a submissão de todos os dados para validar tudo de uma vez. Você vai validando dado a dado conforme eles vão sendo disponibilizados pelo usuário através de um serviço de validação no servidor sob demanda. Mas mesmo fazendo isto, quando o dado for submetido em definitivo, a validação precisa ocorrer novamente (a não ser que não tenha nova submissão e os dados enviados anteriormente já sejam usados, mas tenho dúvidas se isto funciona sempre). A única vantagem desta abordagem é que você evita criar a validação em uma linguagem diferente (usa só o C# e não precisa ter a validação escrita em JS também, facilitando o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), apesar que com o [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/) isto pode mudar). Tem a desvantagem óbvia de gerar mais tráfego e processamento no servidor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 26):

Validar dados sendo enviados pelo usuário só no javascript não é o suficiente por causa de:

- se o usuário desativar o javascript, você pode acabar com dados inválidos no servidor
- se o usuário for malicioso, pode mandar dados inválidos para o servidor
- no caso de um ataque MITM, a validação no servidor seria um dificultador a mais
- validações no servidor fazem um site menos suscetível a robôs maliciosos

Em resumo... vale a pena precaver contra todos esses agentes desconhecidos, fazendo a validação no servidor (que é o agente mais confiável) como sendo a principal... e no javascript, como sendo um agilizador de validação, por não necessitar de ir no servidor.

Nota: *apesar de eu ter mencionado várias formas de ataques que podem ocorrer, não significa que somente a validação no servidor vá resolver tudo. Outras medidas são necessárias contra um Man In The Middle por exemplo, como usar certificado SSL para o seu domínio, entre outras.*

Answer (score 18):

Em um resumo bem simples: a validação em tempo real no cliente promove a usabilidade enquanto a validação no lado do servidor garante a segurança e integridade dos dados.

Answer (score 15):

Em um sentido amplo, não. Aí o escopo envolve não apenas C# e WebForms, mas também outras tecnologias.

Como a natureza do cliente pode ser amplamente modificada (através de outros scripts, por exemplo), não é seguro manter toda a validação apenas no cliente. Os dados enviados para o servidor podem ser perfeitamente alterados sem necessariamente seguir as regras definidas no cliente.

Operações de persistência que envolvam verificação de integridade referencial (vulgo dependência entre entidades de dados) são normalmente feitas do lado do servidor.

Outra coisa é o escopo transacional de uma operação de persistência, que tem a ver também com validação. Em uma aplicação assíncrona, a única maneira de garantir atomicidade de operações é realizando o processamento do lado do servidor.

O caso em que isso não pode ser feito é em Frameworks em que simplesmente não há a separação entre cliente e servidor, que é o caso do [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/).

Answer (score 5):

Um bom exemplo disso, é uma `API` central, ser consumida por diversos clientes, como um client `web` e outro `Android`.

O client `web` pode até fazer a validação, mas e se o `Android` não fizer? Os `dados` serão processados da mesma forma?

Em uma aplicação que estou desenvolvendo, faço validação na `API` (`server`), no client `web` e no client `Android`. Ao menos uma validação básica o `server` tem que ter, para garantir que no minimo os dados estarão sendo tratados corretamente na hora de processá-los.

Answer (score 5):

Bem, tudo depende da regra de negócio envolvida com a validação. Tratando-se de usabilidade devemos executar validações no lado cliente, mas por segurança a única forma de garantir que a validação será feita é no lado servidor, principalmente em ambientes web.

Answer (score 4):

A validação não é suficiente em apenas um dos lados (servidor ou cliente), deve haver uma certa combinação entre ambos.

Em alguns aspectos o melhor é validar no lado do cliente, poupando largura de banda e processamento do lado do servidor, mas ainda assim deverás/poderás validar no lado do server apenas a "real consistência dos dados".

Existem alguma validações que deverão unicamente ser realizadas no lado do servidor, mas estas precisam ser bem feitas e ser o mais eficiente possível.

**Não confie nos dados provenientes dos clientes!**

Answer (score 4):

Validação no lado do cliente e dentro do servidor servem para coisas distintas:
Veja bem, suponha que o cliente tenha certo conhecimento e tente burlar a integridade do seu banco. Se você fizer a validação apenas no lado do cliente ele pode facilmente burlar sua segurança manipulando a DOM por exemplo. Ou seja, dados do cliente não são confiáveis, validando esses dados no servidor a confiabilidade aumenta. Ou seja:

**Validação do lado do cliente** *promove melhor usabilidade e agilidade para o seu usuário*;

**Validação do lado do servidor** *promove integridade e confiabilidade dos dados salvos em seu banco de dados e reduz o risco de que possíveis tentativas de burlarem a segurança acabem por te dar dor de cabeça;*