# Como não permitir números numa textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boas pessoal, estou a tentar fazer uma validação mas ainda não obtive êxito. Quero fazer uma função que não me deixe introduzir números numa `textbox`.

Segue um exemplo de como faço atualmente.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nome_contacto').change(function validar() {
        var textoValida = $('#nome_contacto').val();

        if (textoValida == "1" || textoValida == "2" || textoValida == "3" || textoValida == "4" || textoValida == "5" || textoValida == "6" || textoValida == "7" || textoValida == "8" || textoValida == "9") {
            window.alert("Só letras");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 23):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando uma Expressão Regular. Olhe:

```
  $('#nome_contacto').on('input', function(e) {
    if(/[0-9]/g.test(this.value)){
      alert("Apenas letras");  
    }
  });
```

No caso a expressão foi `/[0-9]/g` que verifica a existência de números, que pode ser substituída por `\d`.

### Teste aqui

```js
$('#nome_contacto').on('input', function() {
  if (/[0-9]/g.test(this.value)) {
    alert("Apenas letras");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="nome_contacto" ></textarea>
```

Mas se você deseja realmente bloquear a entrada de números você pode verificar os `keyCode`. A lista completa destes está [aqui](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

Os `keyCodes` dos números vão de 48 a 57, assim, fiz a verificação `47 > keyCode < 57`.

```js
$('#nome_contacto').keypress(function(e) {
  var keyCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which); // Variar a chamada do keyCode de acordo com o ambiente.
  if (keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="nome_contacto"></textarea>
```

Usei o método [`.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/event/preventDefault) para bloquear a entrada.

### Aqui vai uma alternativa para caso queira apenas números...

Devido a ambiguidade da pergunta, fiz essa opção:

```js
$('#nome_contacto').keypress(function(e) {
  var keyCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (!(keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="nome_contacto"></textarea>
```

No caso basta negar a condição da opção anterior.

Comment: Obrigado. Estou editando com uma maneira de realemente bloquear a entrada, é a isso que se refere?

Comment: Ele quer apenas números, e não tá permitindo números. Eu coloquei apenas um `!`na frente da expressão `!/[0-9]/g` e acho que é isso né....

Comment: Ah, não sei onde tava com a cabeça rsrsrs. Você está com a razão. Mas no caso é só mudar o texto do alert, o resto está de acordo. Na pergunta há afirmação dentro do alert, "Apenas letras"..  E editei a resposta. Dê uma olhada.

Comment: @SamirBraga muito obrigado, o meu objetivo é mesmo bloquear a entrada, o alert é só para testes

Comment: @luisfigueiredo, caso tenha servido perfeitamente.  você pode "aceitar" a resposta, assim o problema será tido como resolvido.

Comment: muito obrigado, foi muito prestável

Comment: Isso aqui está confuso: "quero fazer uma função que não me deixe introduzir números numa textbox." O título diz que é só número, o corpo diz que não é para por número.

Comment: Samir, é o que @Bacco está dizendo, segundo a pergunta é o contrário!

Comment: Entendo @gustavox, fiz segundo o corpo. No próprio `alert()` tem "Apenas lestras". Tinha entendido que o autor queria assim, "o meu objetivo é mesmo bloquear a entrada, o alert é só para testes"...

Comment: E fui olhar agora minha edição na pergunta, e realmente tá confuso, porque no título que editei era "Bootstrap Anular a inserção de numeros em textbox ", e eu mudei porque na perguntava estava " quero fazer uma função que **não** me deixe introduzir numeros ", mas no momento nem percebi a contradição...

Comment: Sim Samir, eu só me toquei porque editei a pergunta, mas agora nem sei mais o que o AP quer, seria interessante que ele esclarecesse melhor. @luisfigueiredo

Comment: Acrescentei uma opção segundo o título. De qualquer forma, está ai..

Comment: Muito bom Samir, e por não poder te dar +1 de novo, segure aí os meus parabéns pela resposta completa. :-) À propósito, nem sei se minha edição no título está correta, ou se incorreto está o corpo do texto. Espero que o AP volte ao site e esclareça... e que marque a resposta como aceita, obv.

Comment: Obrigado.. @gustavox, queria acabar logo com isso rsrsrs... Espero que ele volte mesmo para editar a pergunta como deseja e livras de ambiguidades dessa vez...rs

Answer (score 10):

Uma alternativa às soluções apresentadas é bloquear somente o envio do formulário com os [atributos de validação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation) do HTML5, não a entrada do usuário.

Na verdade, não há como garantir que os dados inseridos estejam de acordo com o previsto, se o usuário quiser badernar ele o fará. Se estiver com o Javascript desabilitado no navegador e você possui uma validação por meio de script, ele passaria tranquilamente. Se ele quiser inspecionar o código-fonte da página e modificar algum atributo no HTML ou um função em um arquivo JS que tratam da validação, ele também passaria numa boa.

Por isso que no servidor devem existir outras checagens, esse assunto já gerou até [uma pergunta sobre a eficiência da validação somente no *client-side*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/4808). A validação no *client* é somente uma tentativa de poupar recursos e evitar realizar requisições à toa para o servidor.

Voltando aos atributos de validação, uma das principais vantagens é eliminar a necessidade de usar Javascript para validar campos. Por outro lado, existe a <s>boa</s> má e velha história do [suporte limitado](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation) em alguns navegadores, por isso a minha resposta pode não ser a melhor solução dependendo dos usuários que acessam (ou podem acessar) a sua página.

#### 1ª solução: `type='text'` com atributo `pattern`

Uma forma é definir o atributo [**`pattern`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) do campo para aceitar somente números.

```html
<input type='text' pattern='\d*'/>
```

#### [**Exemplo online**](https://jsfiddle.net/rnbr/u39Lk9ju/).

---

#### 2ª solução: Usar um campo do tipo `number`

Semanticamente, essa seria a melhor opção para criar um campo que aceita somente números, sem dúvidas. Porém, novamente vem a questão da compatibilidade e [o suporte aos campos **`type='number'`**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number) é péssimo.

```html
<input type='number'/>
```

#### [Exemplo online](https://jsfiddle.net/rnbr/anrudnkd/).

---

Pode até usar o seletor [**`:invalid`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) para informar o usuário que tipo de dados é esperado naquele campo:

```css
p {
  color: #ea6153;
  display: none
}

input:invalid + p {
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<input type='text' pattern='\d*'/>
<p>Ei! Este campo só pode ter números.</p>
```

#### Concluindo

Validações com HTML é algo recente, isto explica o suporte limitado em alguns navegadores. Mas vejo com bons olhos as implementações desse recurso desde que entrou na [especificação](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#client-side-form-validation), só precisamos dar mais um tempo.

Da mesma forma que precisávamos usar Javascript antigamente para fazer animações, por mais simples que fossem — *hoje fazemos isto de forma elegante somente com as CSS3* — logo estaremos usando somente HTML para limitar as entradas em um campo.

O [*Can I Use?*](http://caniuse.com/) é um ótimo site para acompanhar a compatibilidade de uma *feature*. Existem bibliotecas como a [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) que estão aí para detectar essas *features* e ajudar o desenvolvedor a fazer uso de [*polyfill*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) ou do que já existe nativamente.

Answer (score 4):

Apenas uma alternativa, complementando a resposta do Samir Braga.

Exemplo para permitir apenas números num input de texto sem o uso de jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("nome_contato").onkeypress = function(event) {
    var keyCode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (!(keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um código simples. Veja se ajuda.

```js
document.getElementById('texto').addEventListener( 'keyup', function() {

    this.value = this.value.replace( /[0-9]*/g, '' );

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira simples de resolver isso é assim:

```
function isNumber(el) {
    var reg = /[0-9]+/; 
    if ( reg.exec(el) ) {
        return true;
    }
   return false;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nome_contacto').on('change', function() {
        var textoValida = $('#nome_contacto').val();
         if (isNumber(textoValida)) {
            alert("Só utilize letras!");
            return false;
         }
    });
});
```

Mas se você quer simplesmente travar o campo, basta fazer um replace com *keyup* ou *keypress*:

```
$(function() {
    $('#nome_contacto').on('keypress', function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[0-9]+/g,''))
    });
});
```

**input:**

```
<input type="text" id="nome_contacto">
```

Há também maneiras utilizando o atributo **pattern** do HTML5:

```
<input type="text" required="required" name="text" pattern="[^0-9]+$" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Costumo usar o Jquery Mask (https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

depois crio as regras com expressão regular
ex:

```
$('.soNumeros').mask('########', {
            'translation': {
                #: { pattern: /[0-9]/ },
            }
        });
```