# Máscara numérica para campo de data em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Criei um campo Data e com a função JavaScript estou mascarando ela para data, 
mas como usar somente números e não texto?

```js
function mascaraData( campo, e )
{
 var kC = (document.all) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
 var data = campo.value;
 
 if( kC!=8 && kC!=46 )
 {
  if( data.length==2 )
  {
   campo.value = data += '/';
  }
  else if( data.length==5 )
  {
   campo.value = data += '/';
  }
  else
   campo.value = data;
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Mascara data formulario</title>

</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <input type="text" name="outra_data" id="outra_data" maxlength="10" onkeypress="mascaraData( this, event )" />
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Regex é que você precisa!

Comment: Mais como eu posso usar isso ?

Comment: Relacionado: [Como formatar data no javascript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript)

Comment: Dá uma olhada no último código [desta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106730/23400).

Comment: eu quero usar somente Javascript

Answer (score 5):

Encontrei esse exemplo funcional, valida tanto a data no formato dd/mm/aaaa e não permite caracteres que não sejam números, basta adaptar seu `input` para a função, desta forma:

```js
function mascaraData(val) {
  var pass = val.value;
  var expr = /[0123456789]/;

  for (i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
    // charAt -> retorna o caractere posicionado no índice especificado
    var lchar = val.value.charAt(i);
    var nchar = val.value.charAt(i + 1);

    if (i == 0) {
      // search -> retorna um valor inteiro, indicando a posição do inicio da primeira
      // ocorrência de expReg dentro de instStr. Se nenhuma ocorrencia for encontrada o método retornara -1
      // instStr.search(expReg);
      if ((lchar.search(expr) != 0) || (lchar > 3)) {
        val.value = "";
      }

    } else if (i == 1) {

      if (lchar.search(expr) != 0) {
        // substring(indice1,indice2)
        // indice1, indice2 -> será usado para delimitar a string
        var tst1 = val.value.substring(0, (i));
        val.value = tst1;
        continue;
      }

      if ((nchar != '/') && (nchar != '')) {
        var tst1 = val.value.substring(0, (i) + 1);

        if (nchar.search(expr) != 0)
          var tst2 = val.value.substring(i + 2, pass.length);
        else
          var tst2 = val.value.substring(i + 1, pass.length);

        val.value = tst1 + '/' + tst2;
      }

    } else if (i == 4) {

      if (lchar.search(expr) != 0) {
        var tst1 = val.value.substring(0, (i));
        val.value = tst1;
        continue;
      }

      if ((nchar != '/') && (nchar != '')) {
        var tst1 = val.value.substring(0, (i) + 1);

        if (nchar.search(expr) != 0)
          var tst2 = val.value.substring(i + 2, pass.length);
        else
          var tst2 = val.value.substring(i + 1, pass.length);

        val.value = tst1 + '/' + tst2;
      }
    }

    if (i >= 6) {
      if (lchar.search(expr) != 0) {
        var tst1 = val.value.substring(0, (i));
        val.value = tst1;
      }
    }
  }

  if (pass.length > 10)
    val.value = val.value.substring(0, 10);
  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="outra_data" id="outra_data" maxlength="10" onkeypress="mascaraData(this)" />
```

**Referência do código:**

http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/256533-fazer-mascara-para-text-field-para-ddmmaaaa/

Comment: eu usei essa função @Articuno o, mas dei uma enxugada nela pois algumas funcionalidades eu nao utilizei e preferi usar os atributos do HTML

Answer (score 1):

Usa jQuery. Deve atender o que você quer.

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#outra_data').mask('99/99/9999');
        return false;
    });
    </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Então eu preciso usar somente javascript.

Comment: O código que eu te enviei é javascript.

Comment: Acho que ele quis dizer javascript puro, sem framework.

Comment: isso estou procurando alguma solução ou dica para Javascript puro sem Framework.

Comment: Andre, meu bom, jQuery é um universo à parte na [so] e [pt.so], se a pergunta só tem a tag [tag:javascript], devemos responder em JS puro e adicionar uma opção de framework se acharmos que deixa a resposta mais ampla. Anyway, só um par de dicas...

Comment: @brasofilo, a minha resposta foi para tentar ajudar. Muitos recorrem ao stackoverflow quando estão com a corda no pescoço então se você oferecer opções para a solução, pode, pelo menos antecipar uma solução que permita o software ir para a produção. Entendi seu comentário.