# Voltar Focus para um campo apos validação

Tags: javascript, html

boa tarde!

Gostaria de ajuda em uma coisinha aqui, tenho um campo nome do cartão e gostaria de fazer a validação dele para ver se está vazio, fiz e funciona só que a hora que eu clico na mensagem que o alert mandou ele não volta o foco para o input e sim fica dando a mensagem como se estivesse em um loop infinito.Será que alguem consegue me ajudar!!

Segue Código.....

JS

```js
function validanome(){
    if (document.getElementById("nomecartao").value == ""){
        alert("Por Favor Insira o Nome do Titular!!!");
        document.getElementById("nomecartao").focus();
    }
}
```

HTML

```html
<input type="text" class="nomecartao" name="nomecartao" id="nomecartao" maxlength="100" onblur="validanome()" onkeyup="mostrar()">
```

Comment: Sua segunda pergunta é duplicata e evite duas perguntas no mesmo post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106728/como-n%C3%A3o-permitir-n%C3%BAmeros-numa-textbox

Answer (score 1):

O problema do seu codigo ta no `onblur` e quando clicado ele se mantem "em blur" e entra em um looping basta vc trocar para `onChange`.

Utilizar o `onblur` para validação de um campo é muito ruim e causa uma serie de problemas. Se o usuário decide navegar, simplesmente não pode. Quando eles se afastam do campo, são obrigados a voltar. O mais correto seria fazer uma validação após o usuário submeter o formulário e ai sim executar a validação no client-side

```js
function validanome(){
    if (document.getElementById("nomecartao").value == ""){
        alert("Por Favor Insira o Nome do Titular!!!");
        var nome = document.getElementById("nomecartao");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="nomecartao" name="nomecartao" id="nomecartao" maxlength="100" onchange="validanome()" onkeyup="mostrar()">
```

Comment: Giovani muito obrigado, porém eu preciso do evento onblur pois isso é uma caixa de texto e preciso que assim que o foco sair dele preciso que chame a validação

Comment: @JoãoBardella eu expliquei pq o onblur é um problema e substitui o onclick pelo onchange que talvez atenda sua necessidade

Comment: Pq isso é para um sistema de pagamento que estou fazendo conforme o usuário vai digitando os dados já aparecem no cartão de credito ao lado entendeu, por isso não tem botão submeter