# PHP Mailer mandando email sem as informações

Tags: php, phpmailer

Gente, fiz uma landing page na página da empresa e ela envia as informações que as pessoas preenchem para meu e-mail utilizando PHPMailer. A maioria dos e-mails está vindo certinho, com todas as informações necessárias. Porém, alguns e-mails estão vindo vazios, como se as variáveis estivessem vazias; como na imagem abaixo:

[image: Imagem do erro]

O código que envia o e-mail está na página "Obrigado", que recupera os dados via post:

```
            $identificador = $_POST['identificador'];
            $nome = $_POST['nome'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $empresa = $_POST['company'];
            $cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
            $nfuncionarios = $_POST['func'];
            $tipopessoa = $_POST['pessoa'];
            $dificuldade = $_POST['dificuldade'];
            //... recuperar os dados do formulario via post

            require 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
            $Mailer = new PHPMailer();

            // define que será usado SMTP
            $Mailer->IsSMTP();

            // envia email HTML
            $Mailer->isHTML(true);

            // codificação UTF-8
            $Mailer->Charset = 'UTF-8';

            // Configurações do SMTP
            $Mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
            $Mailer->Host = 'br296.hostgator.com.br';
            $Mailer->Port = 25;
            $Mailer->Username = 'desenvolvimento@kamersmarketing.com.br';
            $Mailer->Password = 'minha senha está aqui';

            // E-Mail do remetente 
            // nesse caso email-do-cliente@)
            $Mailer->From = 'aislan@kamersmarketing.com.br';

            // Nome do remetente-cliente
            $Mailer->FromName = 'Kamers Marketing';

            // assunto da mensagem
            $Mailer->Subject = 'Ebook Marketing Digital: Passo a Passo';

            // corpo da mensagem
            $Mailer->Body = '<p><b>'.$nome.', baixou seu ebook "'.$identificador.'"</b>.</p> <p>E-mail para contato: '.$email.'<br><br>Empresa: '.$empresa.'<br><br>Cargo: '.$cargo.'<br><br>Número de Funcionários: '.$nfuncionarios.'<br><br>Tipo de pessoa: '.$tipopessoa.'<br><br>Principal Dificuldade: '.$dificuldade.'</p>';

            // adiciona destinatário /*para onde a mensagem será enviada*/
            $Mailer->AddAddress('desenvolvimento@kamersmarketing.com.br');
            $Mailer->AddAddress('aislan@kamersmarketing.com.br');


            // verifica se enviou corretamente
            if ($Mailer->Send())
            {
            }
            else
            {
                ('Location: marketing-digital-passo-a-passo');
            }
```

Já fiz vários testes no formulário, mas a validação dele está certa, ele não deixa passar campos vazios. Imagino que isso aconteceria se alguém acessar a página "Obrigado" diretamente pela url sem preencher os dados antes, mas é estranho isso acontecer tantas vezes...

Bom, talvez seja a validação, que fiz com pattern no html:

```
<!--no action do form vai para pagina de agradecimento-->
                                <form id="conversion-form" action="obrigado" method="POST" onsubmit="imgloader()">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="identificador" value="Marketing Digital: Passo a Passo">
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label for="name">Nome*</label>
                                        <input type="text" required name="nome" id="name" pattern="^([^*]{3,20})+\ ([^*]{3,20})$" title="Seu Nome Completo, por favor" value="" class="form-control  required">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label for="email">Email*</label>
                                        <input type="email" required name="email" id="email" title="Insira um E-mail V&#225;lido" pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" value="" class="form-control  required">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label for="company">Empresa*</label>
                                        <input type="text" required name="company" pattern="^[^*]{2,20}" id="company" value="" class="form-control  required">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label for="custom_fields_8346">Cargo*</label>
                                        <select required name="cargo" id="custom_fields_8346" class="form-control  required">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
                                            <option value="CEO / Sócio">CEO / SÃ³cio</option>
                                            <option value="Diretor">Diretor</option>
                                            <option value="Gerente/Coordenador de marketing">Gerente/Coordenador de marketing</option>
                                            <option value="Gerente/Coordenador de vendas">Gerente/Coordenador de vendas</option>
                                            <option value="Analista de marketing">Analista de marketing</option>
                                            <option value="Outros cargos">Outros cargos</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label for="custom_fields_8341">NÃºmero de funcionÃ¡rios*</label>
                                        <select required name="func" id="custom_fields_8341" class="form-control  required">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
                                            <option value="1 - 5">1 - 5</option>
                                            <option value="6 - 10">6 - 10</option>
                                            <option value="11 - 25">11 - 25</option>
                                            <option value="26 - 50">26 - 50</option>
                                            <option value="51 - 200">51 - 200</option>
                                            <option value="201 - 1.000">201 - 1.000</option>
                                            <option value="mais de 1.000">mais de 1.000</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label for="custom_fields_17882">Como vocÃª se define*</label>
                                        <select required name="pessoa" id="custom_fields_17882" class="form-control  required">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
                                            <option value="Estudante buscando conhecimento">Estudante buscando conhecimento</option>
                                            <option value="Funcionário procurando informações">FuncionÃ¡rio procurando informaÃ§Ãµes</option>
                                            <option value="Empresa procurando soluções">Empresa procurando soluÃ§Ãµes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label for="custom_fields_17930">Principal Dificuldade*</label>
                                        <select name="dificuldade" id="custom_fields_17930" class="form-control  required" required>
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
                                            <option value="Gerar mais leads">Gerar mais leads</option>
                                            <option value="Leads mais qualificados">Leads mais qualificados</option>
                                            <option value="Aumentar as vendas">Aumentar as vendas</option>
                                            <option value="Aumentar visitas">Aumentar visitas</option>
                                            <option value="Estou totalmente perdido">Estou totalmente perdido</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label><span id="math_expression">3 + 7 = ?</span></label>
                                        <input required type="text" name="captcha" class="math">
                                    </div>

                                <!--fim do formulario*****************-->

                                    <div class="actions">

                                        <input type="submit" class="call_button" value="RECEBER MATERIAL">

                                </form>
```

Vocês sabem se é algum erro meu que não vi?

Comment: Não se importe muito com isso, negativo custa pouca pontuação. A parte da validação seria bom por também, vai que o problema está justamente lá. A parte de envio parece normal, em princípio. Sobre o seu header Location, independente do problema, veja se está no lugar certo, para evitar envios repetidos com F5.

Comment: Seria muito importante validar no PHP também. Nem todos os browsers obrigam a validação do lado do cliente, e a validação do lado do servidor é necessária sempre. A do lado do cliente serve mais como comodidade, para quem está usando não esquecer um campo, por exemplo. Veja esta pergunta, para ter uma idéia do problema: [Usar validação via cliente é suficiente?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13298/)

Comment: Cara, pensei que essa validação com patern seria suficiente. Muito obrigada, vou fazer uma validação com php também.

Comment: De qualquer forma, vamos ver se aparece alguma resposta interessante por aqui. Mas dê uma pesquisada, tem alguns exemplos aqui pelo site.

Comment: você tem que validar a obrigatoriedade do form, senão o o cara só clica no botão enviar e manda tudo vazio.

Comment: Se você colocar na página "Obrigado" uma validação de que a variável $_POST['name'] está preenchida, já vai eliminar todos os e-mails enviados em branco devido a alguém tentar acessar a página diretamente.

Comment: @Maira basicamente o que você precisa pensar são duas coisas: pra validar, basta uma sequência de ifs entre os $post e o require, pra validar os campos, e no caso de não validar, tem um detalhe importante: apresentar o form novamente com os dados que a pessoa já digitou. Para isto, seria o caso de acrescentar nos values do form algo do tipo `value="<?php echo htmlentities( $nome ) ?>"` etc. Nestes casos facilita muito o form ficar na própria página que processa os dados. Os puristas do MVC odeiam isso, mas programador normal faz o que é objetivo, independente de moda (afinal, é PHP, oras).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução para o seu problema seria basicamente esta:

```
require 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

class SendMail extends Exception
{

    private $params;
    private $identificador;
    private $nome;
    private $empresa;
    private $cargo;
    private $nfuncioanrios;
    private $tipopessoa;
    private $dificuldade;

    //dados da empresa

    private $charset = 'UTF-8';
    private $host = 'br296.hostgator.com.br';
    private $auth = true;
    private $port = 25;
    private $username = 'desenvolvimento@kamersmarketing.com.br';
    private $password = 'you password';
    private $from = 'aislan@kamersmarketing.com.br';
    private $fromname = 'Kamers Marketing';
    private $receiveMail = array(
                            'desenvolvimento@kamersmarketing.com.br',
                            'aislan@kamersmarketing.com.br'
        );
    private $layout;
    private $subject =  'Ebook Marketing Digital: Passo a Passo';
    private $isSMTP = true;
    private $isHTML = true;
    public $errors = array();

    public function __construct(array data = array())
    {

        try {
             //valida os campos
            if (!count($data)) {
                $this->errors[] = "Os campos não podem ficar em branco";
            }

            if (!preg_match('/[0-9]+/i', $data['identificador'])) {
                $this->errors[] = "O identificador deve ser somente números";
            }

            if ($data['nome'] == '' || strlen($data['nome']) < 2) {
                $this->errors[] = "O nome não pode ficar em branco";
            }

            if (!preg_match('/\s/', $data['nome'])) {
                $this->errors[] = "Digite seu nome completo";
            }

            if ($data['email'] == '') {
                $this->errors[] = "Digite seu e-mail";
            }

            if (filter_var($data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                $this->errors[] = "Digite um e-mail válido";
            }

            if ($data['empresa'] == '') {
                $this->errors[] = "Digite o nome da empresa";
            }

            if ($data['cargo'] == '') {
                $this->errors[] = "Selecione o seu cargo na empresa";
            }

            if ($data['func'] == '') {
                $this->errors[] = "Selecione o número de funcionários";
            }

            if ($data['pessoa'] == '') {
                $this->errors[] = "Selecione sua definição pessoal";
            }

            if ($data['dificuldade'] == '') {
                $this->errors[] = "Selecione o tipo de critério ou dificuldade";
            }
            $totalErrors = count($errors);

            if ($totalErrors) {
                //verifica se tem algum erro, se tiver cria uma exceção
                $exception = new Exception('Error Message');
                $exception->setParams(array('status' => 1, 'errors' => $this->errors, 'title_errors' => 'Há '.$totalErrors.' erros para corrigir:');
                throw $exception;   
            }

            $this->layout = '<p><b>'.$data['nome'].', baixou seu ebook "'.$data['identificador'].'"</b>.
                             </p> <p>E-mail para contato: '.$data['email'].'<br>
                             <br>Empresa: '.$data['empresa'].'<br>
                             <br>Cargo: '.$data['cargo'].'<br>
                             <br>Número de Funcionários: '.$data['func'].'<br>
                             <br>Tipo de pessoa: '.$data['pessoa'].'<br>
                             <br>Principal Dificuldade: '.$data['dificuldade'].'</p>';


           //se não houver erros ele continua sua aplicação aqui...
           return $this->sendMailToUs($data);


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //as exceções são enviadas para cá, se houver algum erro, ele para o processo e retorna aqui
            return $e->getMessage();

        }
    }

    private function sendMailToUs($data)
    {

        $Mailer = new PHPMailer();

        if ($this->isSMTP) {
           $Mailer->IsSMTP();
        }

        if ($this->isHTML) {
          // envia email HTML
          $Mailer->isHTML(true);
        }

        // codificação UTF-8
        $Mailer->Charset = $this->charset;

        // Configurações do SMTP
        $Mailer->SMTPAuth = $this->auth;
        $Mailer->Host = $this->host;
        $Mailer->Port = $this->port;
        $Mailer->Username = $this->username;
        $Mailer->Password = $this->password;

        // E-Mail do remetente 
        // nesse caso email-do-cliente@)
        $Mailer->From = $this->from;

        // Nome do remetente-cliente
        $Mailer->FromName = $this->fromname;

        // assunto da mensagem
        $Mailer->Subject = $this->subject;

        // corpo da mensagem
        $Mailer->Body = $this->layout;
        // adiciona destinatário /*para onde a mensagem será enviada*/

       if (count($this->receiveMail)) {
           foreach ($this->receiveMail as $key => $value) {
              $Mailer->AddAddress($value);
           }
       }
       if (!$Mailer->Send()) {
            $this->errors[] = "Ocorreu um erro ao tentar enviar o email, causa: ".$Mailer->ErrorInfo:
            $exception = new Exception('Error Sender');
            $exception->setParams(array('status' => 1, 'errors' => $this->errors, 'title_errors' => 'Há '.count($this->errors).' erros:');
       } else{
        return "Mensagem Enviada com sucesso!";
       }
       //se não ocorrer erro, elé irá disparar

       public function setParams(array $params) {
          $this->params = $params;
       }

       public function getParams() {
          return $this->params;
       }

}

if ($_POST) {
   $send = new SendMail($_POST);
   $errorsHandle = $send->getParams();
   if (count($errorsHandle)) {
      $erroHTML = "<ul class=\"errors\">\n";
      foreach($errorsHandle as $erro) {
         $erroHTML .= "<li>{$erro}</li>\n";
      }
      $erroHTML .= "</ul>";
      echo $erroHTML;
   }
   echo $send;
}
```