# Verificação javascript

Tags: javascript

Minha pergunta pode ser meio vaga, mas bem útil para mim.

A questão é, tenho um site onde não estou validando formulários com o `PHP` e sim com `javascript`, existe algum meio do usuário desativar os `javascript's` no servidor e fazer com que envie dados sem passar pela verificação?

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101

Comment: @bigown eu já tinha visto, e isso não respondeu minha dúvida.

Comment: Porque você acha que não respondeu? Lá está claramente a resposta para o que foi perguntado aqui. Eu vi por cima eu achei que podai ser duplicada, agora li melhor e tenho certeza que é.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guilherme, toda e qual quer validação no lado do cliente é ineficaz para assegurar à integridade dos seus dados. Porem elas são importantes, pois o uso delas torna a sua pagina mais amigável e reduz a carga de dados ao servidor, uma vez que terá um numero reduzido de requisições com dados não íntegros.

Por fim, você  não tem qual quer controle sobre o browser, e o seu usuário tem total controle sobre o mesmo, ele pode desativar o javascript, cookies, notificações, storage e etc... Então é "normal" que um usuário acesse a sua pagina sem JavaScript.

Por um outro lado a validação no lado do servidor pode garantir a integridade dos dados, e evitar que dados errôneos ou maliciosos sejam processados, mas se decidir fazer apenas a validação no servidor, o usuário pode acabar com uma péssima experiencia e o servidor sobrecarregado de forma desnecessária.

Então o ideal é fazer a validação nas duas pontas (cliente e servidor).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, isso tirou minha dúvida. Então irei validar no cliente e servidor.