# Como limitar a quantidade de impressões de um documento HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, impressão

Preciso **limitar o número de impressões de um documento HTML**.

Atualmente se o arquivo é gerado (via PHP), registro no banco um flag `sts_impresso = 1`, porém, há vezes em que o usuário não imprimiu por algumas situações:

- Clicou no botão cancelar;
- Fechou a janela;
- Houve problemas de conectividade com internet no momento do download do arquivo a ser impresso.

E nas três situações acima, já havia sido marcado como impresso e o documento fica sem poder ser impresso novamente.

Então pensei em realizar o controle via JavaScript:

```
function imprimir() {
    url = URL_DO_DOCUMENTO_IMPRESSO; // url do documento
    var nw = window.open(url, "popView" , 100, 100, "yes", "yes", true); // abro em nova janela
    $(nw).ready(function () { // assim que carregou, chama o print
        nw.print();
    });
}
```

Como detectar se o usuário clicou no botão **Imprimir** ou no botão **Cancelar** na tela de impressão do browser, ou ainda se ele simplesmente fechou a janela?

A partir da confirmação de que houve impressão, quero fazer uma requisição AJAX para marcar como impresso e em seguida fechar a janela.

Esta é apenas uma ideia de implementação para resolver o problema descrito no título desta pergunta.

Diferentes implementações viáveis para a solução do problema serão bem vindas.

Nota: Sei que tudo no browser dá para burlar e não poderei confiar no código vindo do CLIENTE (Browser), mas preciso pelo menos, minimizar este problema.

Comment: Acaba de descobrir um dos problemas de fazer coisas web. Na verdade qualquer coisa que depende do cliente controlar e informar o servidor terá problemas. Já ouviu falar que [nunca pode confiar no que vem do cliente](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101)? Mesmo que crie um mecanismo que ajude, não pode confiar nele. Ele pode falhar e pode ser burlado. Continuará com o problema. Em uma aplicação nativa é mais difícil falhar, mais fácil detectar e mais difícil burlar (partindo do princípio que não importa muito se for impresso várias vezes, já que isso sempre dá para burlar no cliente).

Comment: É isso mesmo que o @bigown disse, tem também a opção dele imprimir em PDF, e assim ele vai poder imprimir quantas vezes quiser depois, apartir do PDF gerado..

Comment: Além disso que o bigown e o @MarcoGiovanni já disseram, você não tem nem como saber quantas cópias a pessoa escolheu em cada "pedido" de impressão.

Comment: @bigown, MarcoGiovanni e Bacco... teria alguma forma de pelo menos minimizar o problema? ... pelo menos detectar se o usuário clicou em imprimir ou cancelar?

Comment: Não. Nem é universalizado isso entre os browsers. Qualquer coisa que precisa do mínimo de controle personalizado vai sofrer com os limites das aplicações Web, como o @bigown comentou. Mesmo um @ media exclusivo pra print seria acessado só da pessoa ver o preview. Não tem muito o que fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Olá. Tenho um cliente que disponibiliza certificados para impressão para quem participa de suas palestras e workshops.

Uso este código que pra mim funciona perfeitamente em quase todos os principais browsers (IE 7+, Firefox 6+, Chrome 9+, e Safari 5.1+ ).

```
(function() {

var beforePrint = function() {
console.log('Função executada antes da impressão.');
// Aqui você pode detectar se a janela de impressão recebeu uma "call" e foi aberta e executar um pré script para enviar ao seu DB qual foi a ação.
};

var afterPrint = function() {
console.log('Função executada depois da impressão.');
// aqui você pode detectar se a impressão foi concluída e pode enviar a informação para o seu DB.
};

// agora aplicamos a função que detecta a requisição de impressão.
if (window.matchMedia) { // machMedia identifica recursos acionados pelo browser. Pois a janela de impressão é uma aplicação do Sistema operacional para gerenciar mídia de saída, neste caso a saída é via impressora (seja ela virtual - PDF - ou física).
var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
if (mql.matches) {
beforePrint();
} else {
afterPrint();
}
});
}

window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
```

Se o afterprint não for executado, possivelmente houve problema de conectividade ou a impressão foi cancelada. Poderá então, definir um contador de tempo (TimeOut) para isso e chamar um script que informe ao seu DB que a impressão não foi concluída após X intervalo de tempo. Expirar o pedido de impressão, forçando atualizar a página ou fechar a modal/pop-up que continha o conteúdo a ser impresso.

Espero que seja útil.