# Qual a segurança em usar input "password" ou "text"?

Tags: html, input, segurança, senhas

Recentemente estamos em uma onda de usar a combinação de `input` de senhas com a opção de ocultar/exibir a senha (*** -> abc), com a técnica do "olho". Entendo esse propósito, pois melhora muito o lado de `UX` da aplicação.

[image: Eye Password Box]

Sei que um dos motivos de se usar `type="password"` seria de esconder a senha dos olhos "curiosos" em volta. Mas fora isso, gostaria de saber se existe alguma questão de segurança mais profunda que possa envolver o `input` e a senha em si.

Pois se houver, deveríamos fazer com que o usuário mude de volta o `input` para o tipo `password` antes de enviar qualquer informação.

Comment: É so para esconder a senha mesmo, não tem absolutamente nenhum beneficio extra de segurança. Tanto que você consegue pegar o texto integral da senha com javascript, ou simplesmente trocando o tipo dele para text pelo inspetor de elementos.

Comment: Além dos pontos citados pelo @NeuberOliveira há também mais uma coisa, quando o campo é to tipo password, é impossível copiar o conteúdo usando `Ctrl + C` (pelo menos no Linux e no Windows). Mas como ele mesmo afirmou, é possível capturar o conteúdo usando Javascript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Zero**!

É só o que está na pergunta mesmo, ele oculta a senha quando está digitando e mais nada.

Se o computador estiver infectado com algo, vai ler a senha normalmente. E não tem o que fazer quanto a isso. Já vi tentaram (bancos cof cof) fazer coisas para resolver isso e são inócuas.

Nem precisa dizer que para enviar também não vale nada. Só o HTTPS resolve essa questão e resolve bem, claro que se usado corretamente. Só não espere que HTTPS resolve todos os tipos de ataques existentes.

Lembre-se que tudo que vai para o cliente está fora de seu controle e pode ser observado e até mudado sem você saber, por isso dizemos que não se pode confiar em nada que vem do cliente: [Usar validação via cliente é suficiente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101).

Mesmo usando HTTS, você apenas pode confiar que a informação não foi observada e adulterada no transporte, não pode garantir que ele não foi adulterada antes de ser enviada, muito menos observada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Já vi banco grande que tinha tecladinho pra digitar a senha, mas cada caractere era concatenado para uma variável global.... ‍♂️‍♂️