# E possível chamar o mesmo método em todos os Controller asp..net mvc sem precisar repetir o código?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Na minha Controller Home, eu tenho isso:

```
   /// <summary>
        /// Aqui estou trocando o idioma da página de acordo cam a seleção do 
        /// usuário.
        /// </summary>
        /// 

        public ActionResult AlteraIdioma(string LinguagemAbreviada)
        {

            if (LinguagemAbreviada != null)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(LinguagemAbreviada);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(LinguagemAbreviada);

            }

            //aqui estou gravando o cookie com o idioma para que seja recuperado no Global.asax
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Linguagem");
            cookie.Value = LinguagemAbreviada;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            return View("Index");
        }
```

Ele altera o idioma da página e grava um cookie para que a navegação siga no idioma escolhido, mais eu queria saber se eu posso chama isso em todos os controller sem precisar repetir, como ficaria? Agradeço

Comment: Não sei qual é a dúvida. Poder pode, mas depende do que deseja fazer, se precisa mesmo disso, se é assim que deve ser. Provavelmente seria melhor fazer isso de outra forma, mas não é fácil dar um exemplo sem um contexto. O básico é que deveria só pegar o *cookie* e fazer o que deseja sem ficar chamando esse método. Pode, mas não faria sentido fazê-lo. Tenho dúvidas até se esse método está certo. Alias, eu percebi que você aceita qualquer coisa que venha no servidor, né? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101

Answer (score 1):

Existe um recurso nativo do Framework pra isso, chamado de [ASP.NET MVC Filter Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx).

Basicamente, você consegue definir um Action filter pra ser executado ao começou ou fim de cada requisição pra adicionar a sua informação. Por exemplo:

```
public class AlteraIdiomaFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
    // nesse caso, adiciona ao fim da execução de uma Action
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // pega o valor da requisição, no seu caso uma QueryString
        string linguagemAbreviada = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["LinguagemAbreviada"];

        if (linguagemAbreviada != null)
        {
            // tome cuidado ao usar informações vindo do usuário!
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(linguagemAbreviada);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(linguagemAbreviada);
        }

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Linguagem");
        cookie.Value = linguagemAbreviada;

        // adiciona no context, que ele controla o Response que será processado de fato
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
}
```

Você usa o Action filter global registrando no Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{    
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new AlteraIdiomaFilterAttribute());
}
```

Se estiver utilizando o template padrão do ASP.NET MVC 5, ele cria pra você a classe FilterConfig e já chama o método de registro no Global.asax, seria só adicionar o seu filtro:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AlteraIdiomaFilterAttribute());
    }
}
```

No caso do ASP.NET Core, a [documentação oficial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/filters.html#filter-scopes) instrui a adicionar os filtros globais no Statup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new AlteraIdiomaFilterAttribute());
    });

    services.AddScoped<AddHeaderFilterWithDi>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente, pra obter o que você precisa, existem 3 possibilidades (sendo que 2 já foram muito bem explicadas acima):

1. usando um Filter, assim você terá essa funcionalidade globalmente;
2. usando herança, assim você terá essa funcionalidade localmente, isso
   é, terá que incluir o código pra chamada em cada action;
3. usando alguma ferramenta AOP (orientação a aspecto) pra embutir seu
   trecho de código antes da execução de cada método, assim você pode
   escolher fazer por classe, método, biblioteca;

Cada uma dessas soluções tem seus pontos fortes e fracos. A escolha é sua.

Answer (score 0):

Uma das maneiras de se reaproveitar o código entre controllers seria com herança

Não sei se seria o ideal para alterar a linguagem, mas vou manter a resposta focada na pergunta que é para reaproveitar.

Você criar uma classe herdando `Controller`:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public void MeuMetodo()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

A partir daí todos os seus Controllers param de usar a herança de controller e passam a usar a BaseController agora.

```
public class HomeController : BaseController 
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            MeuMetodo();

            return View("Index");
        }
```

Essa é uma forma simples e rápida de fazer o reaproveitamento.