# Regra de campo obrigatório deve estar no backend ou frontend?

Tags: api, validação, estilo-de-codificação, engenharia-de-software, angular

Estou construindo uma aplicação onde o *backend* é uma API e o *frontend* é Angular2.

No cadastro de um usuário faço uma validação na API e se um campo obrigatório não seja preenchido a API devolve um erro informando o campo que deve ser obrigatório.

Minha dúvida é no Angular2, se devo fazer essa regra de obrigatoriedade também, ou se posso usar o da API e simplesmente exibir o retorno da API.

Pois não faz muito sentido eu ter em dois lugares com a mesma regra.

Comment: *Frase:* **Pois não faz muito sentido eu ter em dois lugares com a mesma regra.**, faz sentido se assegurar de todos os problemas que podem ocorrer em validação. Faça a verificação primaria no Angular depois repita na sua linguagem de programação, pois, faz muito sentido ter segurança no Front e Back em sistemas desse tipo. Claro que pode ser feito no `BackEnd` (que no meu entender é obrigatório), mas, quando se faz no `FrontEnd` também seria uma forma de enviar a informação já bem formatada e correta para o `Server Side`. Nos projetos que participei sempre são feitas as duas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Está no caminho certo já que a [validação ocorre no servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101). E não há nada errado em deixar só lá. O único erro é deixar só no cliente.

A experiência com o usuário pode sofrer se esperar que os dados sejam submetidos para analisar se há algo errado. No mínimo deveria usar o poder do Angular para pelo menos fazer verificações conforme os dados vão sendo entrados ou manipulados no *frontend*. Isso já é um ganho enorme. Então ter uma API que permita validação pontual e usá-la já é uma vantagem.

Mas convenhamos que ficar chamando o servidor em cada dado entrado pode ser um exagero. E colocar validações já no próprio cliente pode ser uma simplificação e desafoga um pouco o servidor, inclusive elimina a chance de falhas naquele momento, o que poderia impedir o usuário continuar até a falha ser corrigida (a rede pode ter tido um problema momentâneo. A experiência tende ficar melhor ainda.

Claro que algumas validações não podem ser feitas no lado do cliente, precisam acessar o banco de dados ou até fazer algo que deve ser privilegiado. Não há como garantir privilégios no *frontend*, qualquer um pode burlar ali.

Há quem até faz um cache do banco de dados no cliente, talvez usando [Indexed DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_Database_API) ou algo semelhante, para evitar que o cliente faça requisições desnecessárias ao servidor. Claro que tem que analisar se é o caso, se vai usar com frequência, se não há problema jogar esses dados no cliente, se o volume compensa, etc. Pra falar a verdade quase sempre que compensa fazer isso, provavelmente foi um erro usar tecnologia web.

Então faz bastante sentido fazer no cliente também, mesmo que duplique esforços.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então na teoria em um sistema com "validação dupla" (uma validação front-end e back-end), o usuário comum jamais veria uma mensagem da validação do servidor, apenas a do JS, a menos que ele consiga burlar a "segurança" do front-end e remover um _required_ por exemplo, certo?

Comment: Não faço ideia do que está falando, pra mim toda essa afirmação não faz sentido.

Comment: - verificação de campo vazio no backend.
 - verificação de campo vazio no frontend.
 - User comum faz submit de campo vazio.
 - Verá alerta de campo vazio do frontend.
 - A menos que consiga burlar o frontend, o User comum jamais verá alerta feito pelo backend.

Certo?

Comment: Depende de como a aplicação é feita, pode ser assim.