# Diferença entre validação e máscara

Tags: javascript, html, terminologia, validação

Estou fazendo validações de formulário. Quanto a validação, tudo ocorre bem, mas como formatar os campos de acordo com o dado digitado?

Exemplo: num campo de data, as barras são adicionadas automaticamente, num campo de telefone, os parenteses e os traços são adicionados automaticamente. Essa adições são as chamadas "máscaras"?

Comment: Validação verifica se entrada está correta ou de acordo com o padrão especificado. Máscara define uma formatação para entrada ou dado exibido.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Máscara

Máscara não deixa de ser uma forma limitada de validação. O seu uso exige que os dados entrados estejam em determinado formato.

Através de um padrão você obriga que cada posição digitada tenha um determinado caractere, por exemplo que sempre seja um dígito numérico, ou um ponto, uma barra, que seja uma letra maiúscula, que seja uma faixa numérica (caso típico quando está mascarando uma data e não pode aceitar dia 32, mês 13, ou mesmo dia 30 em mês 02, etc.).

Algumas máscaras podem ser bastante sofisticadas e variáveis conforme os dados vão sendo entrados.

Dependendo de como usar alguns dados tais como pontos, vírgulas e barras podem ser considerados parte do dado digitado ou apenas uma forma de apresentação. Ela pode até mesmo buscar por informações auxiliares que ajudem na formatação obrigatória. Mas não pode ir além do formato dos dados.

Máscaras podem ser usadas apenas para apresentação (saída de dados, formatação). Nesse caso é claro que ela não validará nada.

Muitas vezes a máscara é auxiliada por um [*placeholder*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input), mas ele sozinho não é a máscara já que ele não impede que algo errado naquela posição seja digitada errada.

Apesar de eu evitar muita gente usa uma biblioteca para ajudar montar máscaras, como jQuery e outras mais modernas.

## Validação

A [validação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101) "pura" sempre pode verificar outras coisas, em geral regras mais complexas, e ela normalmente indica se o dado é válido ou não em uma forma booleana.

Ela pode verificar o formato entrado também, mas isso costuma diminuir a experiência do usuário, a não ser que vá fazendo a cada caractere digitado. Mas nem sempre é possível, a validação muitas vezes precisa olhar o todo e não apenas aquele caractere.

Em alguns casos o que é tarefa de um ou de outro pode se confundir, ou até mesmo conflitar se não for bem feito.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

Se a sua função altera controla a forma de um dado, modela sua forma ou impõe determinado formato ao seu dado, isso é considerado uma máscara.

Ex: CPF - (000.000.000-00) / Data - dd/mm/aaaa

Se a sua função faz uma checagem se o seu dado está de acordo com um resultado esperado, isso é considerado uma validação.

```
function verificaNum(valor) {
     if(isNaN(valor)) { // se não for um número
         console.log('não é um número! Valor inválido');
     } 
     else { // se for um número
         console.log('é um número! Valor válido);
     }
}
```

Nota: isNaN retorna um boolean se o valor é ou não um number.

Ex:

```
 isNaN(123) //false
 isNaN('Hello') //true
```

Mas também pode haver o caso de você querer unificar as duas dentro da mesma função. Ai vai depender da sua finalidade....

Answer (score 5):

As máscaras mais do que formatar um elemento de entrada de dados também *valida* o tipo de entrada. Talvez seja interessante que um campo numérico não aceite caracteres, por exemplo.

Validação refere-se se o tipo de dado corresponde ao esperado, além do tipo mas também na semântica. Em um campo numérico, o valor não pode ser superior a *x*, por exemplo.