# Validação: Qual é o método usado neste exemplo?

Tags: javascript, html5, convenções

Estou estudando formas de fazer validação de formulários. Já testei com Javascript, com os recursos do HTML5 e alguns outros métodos, mas todos eles têm algo em comum.

**Sempre tenho que chamar uma função no onclick(), onblur() e similares.**

Não gostaria de fazer isso, já que removendo isto do código, toda a validação seria burlada. Sendo assim, pensei em formas de fazer algum tipo de validação que não tenha que ser chamada ao click de um botao ou coisas parecidas. Este exemplo do site do gmail me deixou curioso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que não são usados patterns ou required do HTML5 ou nenhuma chamada de função Javascript através de clicks. Alguém tem ideia de que modo essa validação foi feita?

Comment: Essa validação de front-end do google também pode ser burlada :)

Comment: Se quer fazer uma validação efetiva, deve fazer no back-end

Comment: De fato, há muitas formas de se fazer a validação no cliente. Mas há uma regra de ouro: nunca confie na validação no cliente. Ela pode ser driblada seja qual for o jeito de implementação (validação HTML5 ou javascript). **Sempre valide também no servidor o dado recebido**. Validação HTML5 é algo bem simples, e o comportamento depende do navegador (ou seja, você não pode customizar muito). Validação JavaScript é algo mais avançado (permite maior customização) e pode ser feita por você ou através de uma biblioteca.

Comment: Os eventos que você se refere (`onclick`, `onchange`) podem estar junto ao input (*inline*), ou podem ter sido declarados em algum outro lugar do código (como é provavelmente o caso do gmail), através de um `addEventListener`, por exemplo, e a decisão de onde colocar depende da organização do seu código e do seu projeto. Na verdade, colocar estes eventos inline é uma prática pouco recomendada, em razão dos princípios de separação de conceitos (html é html, estilo é estilo, script é script). Em linhas gerais, é isto, mas com certeza isso é só um *overview*.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101