# é possivel alterar valores na tela e enviar para o servidor?

Tags: asp.net, segurança

Trabalho em uma aplicação Asp.Net onde alguns valores como preço de pedidos e produtos são recolhidos do form. O total final do pedido é feito em cima das somas dos valores que vem la do formulário, da propriedade text/value.

A minha dúvida é que se algum usuário do sistema pode por exemplo alterar estes valores no HTML que ele tem acesso pelo navegador e enviar valores divergentes para o processamento.

Comment: Posta ao menos uma pequena parte do formulário. Apesar de que a resposta provavelmente vai ser positiva.

Comment: Sim é possível! esse total é 'ilustrativo' para o usuário, na hora de fechar o pedido exiba os valores calculados a partir do server side aí 'pergunte' para o usuário o preço e quantidade desse pedido conferem com o que vc escolhou? você não vai fechar o total baseado no calculo do client side, vai pegar o id dos produtos fazer um consulta e somar/descontar os valores no side server.

Comment: Cara eu não postei código, pois e mais um duvida técnica de conceito e noa um problema com meu código em si mas vou tentar arrumar algo ilustrativo.

Comment: entendi, entao no caso se eu estiver pegando a valor la da tela o cara pode colocar o valor do pedido como 1 real e pagar apenas 1 real por isso, caso eu nao valide no server side?

Comment: O que você estiver pegando de inputs o usuário pode manipular sim com ferramentas de inspeção de código, inclusive se estiver ReadOnly.

Comment: mas no caso os valores estao em labels

Comment: Agora não lembro se o Label será submetido no Asp.Net. Nesse caso você deveria editar a pergunta e especificar que está falando de Label, pois muda bastante o contexto da resposta.

Comment: Essa pergunta pode ajudar: [Usar validação via cliente é suficiente?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13298/usar-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-via-cliente-%C3%A9-suficiente/156326#156326)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a sua dúvida é mais conceitual, a reposta será **sim**, o usuário pode alterar os valores dos preços dos pedidos e/ou produtos e/ou do total no HTML. Por isto, é recomendado sempre fazer as validações tanto no lado do cliente quanto no lado do servidor.

**Atualizado**

[Neste link](https://amirton.wordpress.com/2009/05/14/perigos-da-validacao-client-side-ou-sempre-valide-client-e-server-side/) você encontrará os perigos da validação somente no lado do cliente.