# Qual atributo HTML não pode ser modificado?

Tags: html, segurança, atributos

Usando PHP eu exibo uma tabela, na `id` de cada `li`, eu coloco a `id` do registro que esta no banco de dados. Uma vez elas exibidas, tenho uma opção que exclui o registro, faço isso através de AJAX, pego a `id` daquela `li`, e mando pro PHP deletar.

Mas percebi que se eu usar o Developer Tools, "famoso F12", e mudar manualmente a `ID` da `li`, ele vai pegar essa nova ID que eu coloquei. Dessa forma o projeto que estou fazendo fica vulnerável dependendo de quem o use. Digo isso pois tem muita coisa que estou usando esse método. Tem algum atributo que o usuário não possa editar ou algum outro método mais seguro?

Comment: Resposta mais longa: **Não**.

Comment: O jeito é validar sempre no backend.

Comment: Normalmente não precisaria fazer nada de especial no html. Uma aplicação bem escrita não vai deletar com base só no ID, e sim nas credenciais do usuário. Se o usuário tem permissão para deletar, tanto faz se foi pelo devtools ou se foi pela interface original. O que pode estar acontecendo de errado é sua aplicação não validar as credenciais. Isso seria um problema real da aplicação, diferente do caminho buscado na pergunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não existe, na verdade não é só HTML, é em qualquer coisa, sempre que você depender de um cliente você estará vulnerável, por isso nunca deve confiar em nada que vem do cliente, tudo pode vir de forma inesperada. [Nunca confie no cliente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101)!

Imagine que na maioria dos softwares existentes, principalmente web só funcionam por coincidência, porque em geral ninguém mexe, é raro o programador que valida todas entradas de dados e só aceita o que realmente é adequado.

Aplicações *não web* dificultam um pouco mais porque exige um conhecimento técnico que poucos têm, mas para web, qualquer curioso pode detonar sua aplicação.

Pensa bem, qual a diferença entre a pessoa acessar um `id` pela sua página normal ou pelo Dev Tools? Tem alguma situação que a pessoa não pode acessar esse `id`? Garanta no servidor que isto não seja possível. Não tem outra forma.

E garanta que o servidor não está vulnerável. Garanta que a aplicação não pode ser comprometida, caso contrário nem no servidor terá segurança.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Intendo, então por exemplo, no meu BD, tenho os endereços do cliente, eu tenho a id e idUser. Eu teria que verificar se id enviada tem o mesmo idUser do usuário que esta logado. Se sim prossegue com a ação, caso contrato seria algum usuário tentando modificar algo correto, eu apenas interrompo a ação e exibo um alerta. Tento sempre fazer validação front e back.

Comment: É por aí. Não tem como impedir que usuários façam algo errado de boa ou má fé, dá para evitar que aconteça, dá para restringir o que ele pode fazer, dá para auditar, reverter, dá para evitar que pessoas não autorizadas mexam onde não podem.

Answer (score 2):

Não tem como impedir. Se o cliente alterar um código que será enviado ao servidor, é o servidor que deverá validar: verificar se o valor existe, se o valor recebido é válido, se o cliente que o enviou tinha autorização pra isso, etc etc...

Mas é sempre bom fazer uma pré-validação *frontend* também, pois poupa requisições ao servidor.

No seu exemplo, se o cara trocar id=10 pra id=12, por exemplo, e de forma normal isso não fizer diferença, ele só estará trocando 6 por meia-dúzia. Agora, se ele trocar id=10 por id=13 e o valor "13" não estiver incluído nos valores em que esse usuário pode mexer, seu `backend` deverá saber disso e impedir que o script prossiga.

Answer (score -3):

Você poderia gerar chaves de validação para seus inputs e registrar num array, daí antes de submeter o formulário ou qualquer outra ação, pode checá-los usando JS.

Ex:

```
<input id="1" data-validation="b89eaac7e61417341b710b727768294d0e6a277b">
```

Neste input o data-validation é um hash SHA1 gerado com o ID do campo original e a informação do cabeçalho com data e hora de carregamento da página. Isto é só um exemplo de como você pode manter controle do ID. Assim você consegue validar tudo antes de submeter.

Geralmente, eu crio algumas camadas de validação no front e no backend ... e não me preocupo com as modificações em tempo real, pois sempre são filtradas em uma ou outra camada.