# Evitar a alteração da informação no HTML

Tags: html, aplicação-web

Olá,

Eu estou a desenvolver uma aplicação web que, em determinadas páginas, tem uma tabela com informação e tenho um evento (em jQuery) que está sobre as linhas da tabela que quando clicadas passam para uma página de detalhe. A minha dúvida está relacionada com a forma com que eu identifico as linhas.

Neste momento estou a fazer o seguinte: `<div class="test" data-id="3">`.
No entanto, qualquer pessoa que saiba utilizar as ferramentas de programador, pode ir alterar o valor e passa a ver outro tipo de informação.

Existe alguma de ter este identificador mas que não possa ser alterado tão facilmente?

Comment: Pelo que vejo, você quer que somente a pessoa que criou essa linha, possa fazer alterações nela? (evitando assim que outras pessoas usem esse id e façam alterações sem permissão?)

Comment: Tudo que tiver no browser o usuário vai conseguir modificar. Você até pode dificultar criando algum tipo de criptografia e tal, mas sempre vai ter que validar a informação.

Comment: Uma excelente resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13298/usar-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-via-cliente-%C3%A9-suficiente

Comment: Eu dar um exemplo mais prático para contrastar com este que dei. No outlook.com, a primeira coisa que se vê é uma lista de e-mails e só depois de clicar num é que abre o e-mail. Já vi o código fonte e não me pareceu que houvesse algum identificador do e-mail. Eu queria saber como é que posso fazer na minha aplicação?