# Como posso extrair valores de um input do Javascript, mas utilizando a validação do HTML

Tags: javascript, html, formulário

```
 <form><label for="NUMERO">Digite um número</label>
 <input type="number" name="num" id="NUMERO" min="0" max="100">
 <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
 </form>
```

Gostaria que no javascript o número foi extraido e o formulário validasse, de forma que a página não seja atualizada. Por favor, me explique etapa por etapa

Answer (score 1):

Coloque o atributo `required` que ao fazer o submit o HTML irá exigir que o campo seja preenchido. Para cancelar o evento submit, use `preventDefault();`, com isso o formulário não será enviado e a página não será recarregada.

Para isso, você deve criar uma função que receba o evento submit do formulário. Você pode pegar o formulário com `document.querySelector("form")` e detectar o submit com `onsubmit`:

```js
document.querySelector("form").onsubmit = function(e){
   // o "e" recebe o evento submit.
   // Em vez de "e", você pode usar outra letra ou palavra,
   // como "event", "x", "y", "evento", "ev" etc..
   // Eu uso "e" por costume. Cada programador tem seus costumes
   // em criar nomes de variáveis
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log("Formulário ok!");
}
```

```html
<form><label for="NUMERO">Digite um número</label>
<input type="number" name="num" id="NUMERO" min="0" max="100" required>
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

O `querySelector` seleciona o elemento que você especificar no seletor. No caso acima, eu peguei o elemento `form`, que é o formulário.

Chamando uma função não-anônima:

```js
document.querySelector("form").onsubmit = f;
function f(){
   console.log("Formulário ok!");
   return false;
}
```

```html
<form><label for="NUMERO">Digite um número</label>
<input type="number" name="num" id="NUMERO" min="0" max="100" required>
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

O `return false;` também irá cancelar o envio do formulário.

Comment: Eu gostaria que no  "document.querySelector("form").onsubmit = function(e){" ,   em vez de "function(e){..}" fosse uma função que eu chamasse, ex.: "var 2 = Ok(e);   function Ok(e){...codigo...}"

Comment: @Pedro Aí já foge do escopo da pergunta. Há formas de fazer o que vc quer. Dá uma pesquisada ou você pode fazer uma outra pergunta no site com esse novo assunto.

Comment: @dvd Ultima pergunta, tem como eu fazer isso com addEventListener ?

Comment: tem sim: `document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e){ código });`

Comment: @dvd Ah, na verdade, acho que me expressei mal no penúltimo comentário, eu queria usar em vez de uma função anonima, uma função definida, mas não consigo

Comment: Ahh, agora funcionou. Obrigado por ter ajudado e foi mal o incômodo!

Comment: Consegui somente com o .onsubmit, mas ok]

Comment: @Pedro Não tem como cancelar o evento com addEventListener chamando uma função externa.

Comment: Pedro, não deixe de marcar ✔️ na resposta. Isso faz parte do site é é importante.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo que faça a validação no próprio JavaScript por ser mais seguro, pois no HTML é possível que o usuário remova a tag de validação por meio do inspencionar elemento, ficando da seguinte forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#formCadastro").on("submit", function(event) {
    var numero = $("#NUMERO").val();
    if(numero != ''){
     if(numero >= 0 && numero <= 100){
        //realiza action do form
        return true;
      }
    }
    //não execute action do form
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formCadastro">
  <label for="NUMERO">Digite um número</label><br>
  <input type="number" name="num" id="NUMERO"><br>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Para retirar a validação do js também não é muito complicado...

Comment: *"faça a validação no próprio JavaScript por ser mais seguro"* - na verdade, o mais seguro **mesmo** é validar no servidor: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298

Comment: Quis dizer que é melhor que HTML puro..