# Utilizar boas práticas ou a forma correta de se armazenar um ID

Tags: php, javascript, html

Atualmente quando preciso alterar algum dado de clientes, armazeno o ID em um `input hidden`, mas isso fica visível caso você inspecione elemento dando a liberdade para alguém que tenha mais experiência manipular o sistema.

Existe alguma forma correta de se fazer isso? Alguma boa prática?

Comment: É o seu backend que deve decidir o que é válido. Tudo no front está sujeito a alteração. Se o cliente consegue ver o ID, alterar e passar outro ID como se fosse "válido" pro backend, então seu sistema tem falhas graves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não fica muito visível. Fica suficientemente visível.

Se o seu sistema permite que algo errado seja feito só porque alguém sabe qual é o ID, então seus sistema é muito falho. Conserte ele, não tente inventar proteções artificiais em sentido.

Está errado qualquer sistema que não valide cada mínima ação do usuário antes de tomar uma decisão e uma ação que mude estado no sistema. E adivinhe? Uns 99% dos sistemas permitem usuários fazer coisas não esperadas e comprometer em algum grau o que não poderia fazer.

As pessoas precisam aprender desenvolver software do jeito correto e esse jeito nunca é pegando uma informação aqui ou ali. É necessário método científico, aprendizado estruturado, entendimento profundo de toda a base do que está fazendo e saber qual é seu contexto, por isso nunca procure por boas práticas.

Boas práticas servem como alerta para algo que alguém já pensou sobre o assunto, não como guia definitivo do que fazer. A maioria tem falhas e não foco no seu contexto.

Tudo o que vem de fora do sistema, principalmente as que podem ser acionadas por um usuário de forma legítima ou não deve ser validada. Só deve aceitar o que for possível. Um dos erros que se comete é tentar impedir o errado. Você nunca saberá tudo o que pode ser errado. Então proibia tudo e aceite só aquilo que é aceitável naquele contexto.

A pessoa pode ver determinada informação se passar o ID? Ok, então mande pra ela. Se ela não puder não mande. Se pode em dada circunstância, se pode se ela for uma pessoas com uma determinada credencial, ok, então verifique se atende os critérios antes de mandar. Isso se torna ainda mais importante se ela puder mudar o dado.

Se o dado for mudado, será que precisa de autorização extra de alguém? Em alguns casos precisa, então faça um passo extra. De qualquer forma registre tudo oque foi alterado, ou mesmo acessado em boa parte dos casos.

Há situações que um sistema de alerta é um meio termo entre só registrar o que o foi feito e pedir para alguém autorizar a ação. Existe um mecanismo chamado alçada e é um termo que quase nenhum programador usa, um enorme erro.

> al·ça·da
> substantivo feminino
>
> 1. Limite dos poderes concedidos.
> 2. Jurisdição, supremacia.
> 3. [Figurado]  Esfera de .ação.
> 4. Apelação.
> 5. Tribunal ambulante que administrava justiça e alçava agravos.
>
> "alçada", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/al%C3%A7ada [consultado em
> 28-07-2018].

[Usar validação via cliente é suficiente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).