# Quais as consequências de não trabalhar na tipagem de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, design-pattern, tipagem

Quero criar uma aplicação aonde o cliente pode criar um novo formulário ou tabela, em que ele pode escolher o tipo de dado do campo, como número, texto, binário, etc.

Uma solução "fácil", seria fazer uma validação na *front-end*, e no banco de dados, colocar todos os campos como *string*. Eu não sei aonde li isso, mas qualquer solução fácil demais está fadada ao fracasso, e minha intuição diz isso também.

No entanto, nunca vi uma discussão listando todos os possíveis problemas de não fazer a tipagem de dados. Os problemas não devem ser somente de segurança e escalabilidade. Deve ter problemas de design aí que ainda não vi ser discutido.

Não penso em limitar essa conversa a uma linguagem, mas trabalho com Python e PHP (não trabalharei com C# ou Java, ainda que sejam tipados. Motivos não fazem escopo da dúvida).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Os problemas não devem ser somente de segurança e escalabilidade.

Esses são os principais, a segurança de tipos, que tem a ver com **robustez**, e com a **facilidade** que a tipagem dá de administrar grandes bases de dados já que o compilador e ferramentas, como IDE, podem ajudar detectar erros e impedir uso equivocado, além de organizar melhor. Quando se é obrigado pensar nos tipos as pessoas tendem a produzir códigos melhores.

Não à toa programadores de linguagens de tipagem dinâmica costumam ser mais fracos em relação aos de tipagem estática. E cria um ciclo vicioso, onde essas linguagens que já não prezam pela robustez atraem muitos programadores com baixa qualificação, e justamente por elas treinarem em linguagem que não as exige pensar, raramente elas se tornam programadoras melhores.

Claro que tem exceções e há programadores bons usando linguagens dinâmicas, mas é exceção e não regra. E é comum haver um [efeito Dunning-Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect). E obviamente muitos programadores ruins usam linguagens estáticas.

O outro motivo não citado é a perda de **performance**. O computador é tipado por natureza e sabe lidar com certos dados nativamente, fazer de conta que não tem tipo obriga ter um mecanismo pra fazer funcionar e isto tem custo.

> Deve ter problemas de design aí que ainda não vi ser discutido

*Design* quem faz é o programador, não é a linguagem, então depende dele. A tipagem dinâmica deixa fazer *designs* horrendos e pode até funcionar. A tipagem estática também permite, mas menos. Mas claro, com "vontade" todos podem fazer os piores *designs* possíveis usando qualquer ferramenta. Preferia que as pessoas usassem essa vontade toda para produzir coisas mais interessantes.

Mas o sugerido na pergunta é lidar tudo como *string*, o que é conhecido informal e jocosamente como *stringly typed*, em alusão ao *strongly typed*.

Existe uma perda de performance óbvia porque qualquer cálculo a ser feito precisa de conversão, e tratar um *array* de caracteres custa mais que lidar um números. E precisa de verificação antes de usar, e tratar erros que não existiriam se já soubesse o tipo de antemão.

Nesse caso nem é problema de ter tipagem dinâmica, é tratar tudo como uma coisa só, que é pior ainda. A não ser que tudo seja descrição. Onde só descreve dados muda pouco, afinal o tipo certo para descrições é a *string*.

Se vai fazer outras operações terá que fazer conversões todas as vezes. E verificar se ela foi possível. Em muitos casos terá que que criar funções auxiliares para isto, e só depois disto fazer alguma operação. Tudo isso custa caro para executar e para desenvolver, é complexo e dá espaço para vários problemas ocorrerem.

Um exemplo: o usuário cria um campo para guardar data. Aí quer a quantidade de dias de atraso para hoje. Como fazer isso com algo que é apenas texto? Recriando tudo o que já existe sendo data. Mais lento, mais complexo e menos robusto.

## Software flexível

Na verdade fazer o que foi descrito na pergunta é algo bastante mais complexo do que as pessoas acham que é, e mesmo pessoas experientes vivem tentando e fazem errado. Tem que pensar em muita coisa, e no fundo acabará criando praticamente um compilador e uma nova biblioteca para lidar com isto adequadamente. E provavelmente cairá no que se chama [Greenspun's Tenth Rule Of Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule):

> Any sufficiently complicated C or Fortran program contains an ad-hoc, informally-specified, bug-ridden, slow implementation of half of Common Lisp.
>
> -- Philip Greenspun

Ou seja, as pessoas tendem a inventar mecanismos sofisticados para problemas simples, e tendem a deixar de usar o que já tem e escolher a melhor decisão de *design*.

O problema também é conhecido como [Turing tarpit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_tarpit) tende a um [efeito Inner-platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect) ou adotando o [princípio de Peter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Peter_principle). Veja também: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski#Principles.

Não entendeu porque coloquei esses *links*?

Parou pra pensar que deixar o usuário criar dados do jeito que eles querem sem dar o poder deles programarem algo, serve pra nada? A não ser que seja tudo descritivo, o que aí nunca dá problema e não cria dificuldade.

Se você for programar em cima do que eles criaram, então é mais fácil eles não criarem, afinal, em tese, você será capaz de criar melhor que eles e dará menos trabalho. A única forma de dar sentido neste tipo de mecanismo com alguma razão é criar uma ampla infraestrutura complexa para lidar com o que o usuário fará.

Melhora um pouco se já for um tipo de data, aí pelo menos pode usar o que tem pronto, sem precisar converter e já validado. Mas ainda não é simples.

Em geral esse tipo de flexibilidade é melhor adotada para consumir dados existentes e não para criá-los. Aí um leigo pode fazer sem maiores problemas, se não for algo complexo. E se ele errar, em consulta não tem potencial de causar muito estrago. Mesmo nestes casos não serve para todos.

Note que o problema não é só guardar tudo como texto, é guardar algo sem semântica. Tudo fica mais complexo de lidar. E ajuda pouco. Mesmo que use outros tipos, pode não ser suficiente.

Engenheiros já erram muito no *design* de sistemas, o que acaba sendo normal dada a dificuldade com que lidamos. Programadores que não são engenheiros fazem muito errado, quase sempre. Imagine usuário (conheço alguns melhores que certos "programadores"). Não dê fósforo pra criança brincar.

Depois de décadas trabalhando exatamente com o descrito na pergunta sei o que pode dar ao usuário e o que não pode, o que facilita e o que é engodo, o que é bom para o usuário e o que é só facilitador para o programador. O resumo: dê pouco, e se absolutamente necessário, e ainda só se souber fazer isso muito bem, que é muito mais complicado de fazer.

Desenvolver software é difícil, a não ser em casos muito triviais e que já possuem solução pronta, o que não deveria exigir um software novo. E é engenharia, não deixe se enganar. O usuário não sabe desenvolver software porque ele não é engenheiro, assim como alguns programadores não o são.

Alguns podem achar que isso é [torre de marfim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivory_tower) ou síndrome do aquário (termo antigo pro pessoal de TI que se fecha no seu departamento e não quer que ninguém se meta). Mas vemos o tempo todo usuários e programadores ruins fazendo coisas horríveis por não entenderem o que estão fazendo, e isso é claramente algo ruim. É tanto que quase não se acha a exceção que confirme a regra, ainda que exista. Deixar na mão do usuário não costuma dar certo.

Leia isto: [Usar validação via cliente é suficiente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Seu maior problema será em como trabalhar os dados. Os bancos de dados criam recursos para certos tipos de dados assim como as linguagens de programação, e você estará jogando tudo isto fora ao tratar tudo como string. Imagina a situação em que você terá que fazer uma simples soma, algo tão simples pode se tornar complexo devido a quantidade de dados e a falta de uso do recurso correto.
No seu caso, fazer certo e errado é o mesmo esforço, se o cliente seleciona que o valor é numérico cria o numérico no banco.
Tem coisas que são tão antigas e maduras que não vale apena ir contra, pois se houvesse alguma divergência neste conceito, já existiriam produtos que não o seguiriam.