# Não deixar incluir data 50 anos para trás no banco de dados

Tags: java, primefaces, data

Tenho um sistema JSF e PrimeFaces 4.0 e tenho um campo `<p: calendar>` no qual fiz o tratamento para não carregar datas no calendar do dia atual até -50 anos.

Mas mesmo assim o usuário consegue digitar ela pelo teclado e inserir no banco de dados.

Preciso de um método para não deixar incluir uma data desse tipo, qual seria a melhor forma de fazer?

Segue um exemplo da classe:

```
public class DocumentoClienteModel  {

    private Date dateInicio;

    public Date getDtInicio() {
        return dtInicio;
    }

    public void setDtInicio(final Date dtInicio) {
        this.dtInicio = dtInicio;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oi Bruno, você consegue implementar javascript na sua tela?

Comment: Acho que sim preciso so me certificar da segurança, tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Se sim, posso te ajudar!

Comment: Posso sim, como poderia?

Comment: Só 1 minuto....

Comment: De antemão, se a minha resposta for útil, teria como votar positivamente nela e marcar como resposta útil? Ajudaria muito :)

Comment: Com certeza ! Votarei sem problemas

Comment: Publiquei uma resposta, me diga se o ajudou, certo? Abraços!

Comment: Vi respostas dando solução para resolver seu problema no front-end. Mas você sabe que o usuário pode burlar tudo que está no navegador, né? Não entendo nada de Java, mas provavelmente, a lógica poderia ser desenvolvida no backend, para validação se a data é a que você não quer deixar inserir. 

Digo isso porque você citou "banco de dados". Se não quer deixar inserir no banco de dados, valide no backend. Se fizer como as respostas disseram, inclusive para usar `readonly`, é bem fácil de tapear seu aplicativo.

Comment: Sobre validação no backend vs frontend: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/112052

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria um método para pegar a data mínima e setar no componente, ficando dessa forma:

```
public Date getMinDate(){
    Date minDate = new Date();
    Calendar calendarData = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarData.setTime(minDate);
    calendarData.add(Calendar.YEAR,-50);

    return calendarData.getTime();
}
```

no xhtml:

```
    <h:form>
        <p:calendar value="#{mBDates.minhaData}"  mindate="#{mBDates.minDate}" id="dtLast"></p:calendar>
        <p:message for="dtLast" display="icon" />
    </h:form>
```

E para o caso do usuário espertinho digitar a data na mão, colocaria uma validação antes de salvar:

```
public boolean dataValida(Date data){
    int compare = data.compareTo(getMinDate());
    //se a data for igual ou menor a data minima retorna falso
    //e não salva meu formulario, lançando uma advertencia para o usuário
    if(compare == 0 || compare == -1)
        return false;
    //senão retorna que a data é valida e salva meu formuladrio
    return true;
}



    public void salvarMeuForm(){
        if(!dataValida(minhaEntidade.getMinhaData()))
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro!", "Data não permitida."));
   }
```

Comment: Dá para fazer o método `dataValida` em uma linha: `return data.after(getMinDate());` - a data só é válida se for depois (`after`) de `getMinDate()`

Comment: O codigo para pegar a data minima eu havia conseguido fazer , agora so estou com dificuldade na parte do do usuario digitar na mao, crio  public boolea dataValida(date Date ) na minha classe como  disse e no front preciso colocar mais alguma coisa ?

Comment: @BrunoS se fosse eu fazendo esse formulário, colocaria uma mensagem de erro quando o usuário tentar salvar quando digitou uma data inválida, vou editar minha resposta e colocar o exemplo com a mensagem.