# Verificar a existência de caracteres especiais em uma string utilizando Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso validar um campo de senha que deve conter ao menos um caractere especial. Há alguma expressão Regexp para fazer esta verificação?

E.g.

```
var patt = [a-z]; // verifica a existência de letras minúsculas 
var patt = [A-Z]; // verifica a existência de letras maiúsculas
var patt = [0-9]; // verifica a existência números
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apenas para complementar a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/342609/112052), gostaria de dar uma outra alternativa para a solução.

Você disse que quer validar um campo de senha e permitir que ele tenha caracteres especiais (além de letras e números, que eu entendi que também devem ser aceitos).

Ao usar `\W`, você realmente vai aceitar os tais caracteres especiais (tudo que não for alfanumérico), mas pode acabar aceitando coisas demais que talvez não devesse. Vamos entender melhor vendo em detalhes o que de fato significa o `\W`.

---

Basicamente, o `\W` é um [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#negated) que significa "tudo que não for `\w`" (repare a diferença entre `W` maiúsculo e `w` minúsculo). E o `\w` significa "letras de `A` a `Z` (maiúsculas ou minúsculas) **ou** dígitos de `0` a `9` **ou** o caractere `_`".

Portanto, `\W` significa "tudo que não for letra de `A` a `Z`, dígito de `0` a `9` ou `_`". E esse é o problema, porque é **tudo** mesmo!

O `\W` pode até pegar os caracteres especiais (incluindo aqueles geralmente aceitos em senhas, como `$` e `@`), mas também vai aceitar muitos outros que **talvez** não devessem ser aceitos em um campo de senha. Só para citar alguns exemplos:

- caracteres "invisíveis", como [espaço em branco](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm), [tabulação](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0009/index.htm), o [`\0` (NULL - ASCII 0)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm) etc.
- caracteres de outros alfabetos (japoneses, coreanos, árabes etc...) *****
- emojis e outros símbolos, como o [símbolo de copyright](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a9/index.htm), por exemplo *****

* <sup><sub>*aceitar esses caracteres não seria um problema, coloquei uma observação no final*</sub></sup>

Para todos esses casos, a regex `/\W|_/` retorna `true`, como podemos ver nos exemplos abaixo:

```js
let regex = /\W|_/;

// espaço (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm)
let space = " ";
console.log("caractere: [" + space + "]");
console.log(regex.test(space)); // true

// TAB (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0009/index.htm)
let tab = "\t";
console.log("caractere: [" + tab + "]");
console.log(regex.test(tab)); // true

// \0 (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm)
let asciizero = "\u0000";
console.log("caractere: [" + asciizero + "]");
console.log(regex.test(asciizero)); // true

// caractere japonês (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/337B/index.htm)
let jp = "\u337b";
console.log("caractere: [" + jp + "]");
console.log(regex.test(jp)); // true

// emoji (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm)
let emoji = "\u{1F4A9}";
// se a linha acima não funcionar (browsers mais antigos), troque por "\uD83D\uDCA9"
console.log("caractere: [" + emoji + "]");
console.log(regex.test(emoji)); // true

// copyright (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a9/index.htm)
let cr = "\u00a9";
console.log("caractere: [" + cr + "]");
console.log(regex.test(cr)); // true


// mais alguns exemplos
console.log(regex.test('^')); // true
console.log(regex.test('ñ')); // true
console.log(regex.test('௸')); // true
```

O caso do espaço e <kbd>TAB</kbd> pode acontecer se o usuário copiar e colar a senha de algum outro programa/editor e vier algum desses caracteres "escondido" na string. Isso vale também para uma série de outros caracteres que não são visíveis, mas podem estar na string sem sabermos. O Unicode define [vários caracteres diferentes para espaço](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm), por exemplo - e `\W` aceita todos eles (além de quebras de linha e outros [caracteres de controle](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cc/list.htm), e muitos outros).
Cabe a você decidir se vai querer aceitar uma senha como `a$      123`.

Isso pode ser minimizado se você [validar novamente a senha no servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/112052), antes de salvá-la no banco (mas se usar a mesma regex com apenas `\W`, não vai adiantar nada, pois também vai deixar passar esses caracteres).

Já os emojis, caracteres japoneses/árabes/etc e símbolos como o `©`, bem, você decide se deve aceitá-los ou não. Se estes forem caracteres permitidos na sua senha, tudo bem. Mas se esses caracteres não devem ser aceitos, usar `\W` não é a melhor alternativa.

Não estou dizendo que a [resposta que sugeriu `\W`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/342609/112052) está errada (<sup><sub>*inclusive votei nela, pois faz o que foi pedido*</sub></sup>). Ela de fato valida o que você precisa (caracteres especiais - tudo que não for letra ou número). O problema é quando ela começa a validar coisas que talvez não devesse.

Usar `\W` pode cair nesse caso: ela faz o que você quer (pega tudo que não é letra ou número), mas faz mais que isso: pega outros caracteres que talvez você não queira. Enfim, se para você tudo bem aceitar emojis, caracteres invisíveis, [símbolos matemáticos](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sm/list.htm), [acentos](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm) e [muitos outros](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/So/list.htm) caracteres definidos pelo Unicode, que não são letras de `A` a `Z` nem dígitos de `0` a `9`, pode usar `\W`. Mas se você quer limitar os caracteres para somente aqueles que suas senhas podem ter, pode continuar a leitura, pois vamos usar uma regex um pouco mais complexa, porém menos propensa a esses falsos positivos.

---

### Alternativa ao `\W`

Primeiro você deve definir quais caracteres especiais vão ser considerados, pois a definição "caracteres especiais" é um pouco vaga. Existem muitos caracteres que podem ser chamados de "especiais" (e se considerarmos "tudo que não for alfanumérico", já vimos que o resultado é abrangente demais).

Por exemplo, `^` (acento circunflexo, sem nenhuma letra) pode ser considerado? E se for uma letra com acento: `ñ`? O hífen? A vírgula? Parênteses? Sinais de pontuação? Cada site na internet tem suas próprias regras do que é permitido ou não em uma senha, então "caracteres especiais" é algo que varia bastante para este contexto. Por isso a primeira coisa a fazer é definir exatamente o que é um caractere especial no seu caso.

Uma vez definida a lista de caracteres especiais, uma solução é colocar todos esses caracteres entre colchetes. Os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) e fazem a regex aceitar qualquer caractere dentro deles. Por exemplo, `[@#]` significa "o caractere `@` **ou** o caractere `#`.

Então eu poderia ter algo como `[@!#$%^&*()/\\]`, que corresponde a qualquer um dos caracteres entre `[` e `]`. Note que para o caractere `\` eu tive que colocar `\\`, pois a `\` sozinha serve para escapar caracteres que têm significado especial na regex. Se eu colocasse apenas um `\`, eu estaria escapando o `]` e ele seria interpretado como o próprio caractere "fecha-colchetes" e não como o delimitador de uma classe de caracteres.

Um detalhe é que toda a expressão `[@!#$%^&*()/\\]` corresponde a apenas **um** caractere (que pode ser qualquer um que está dentro dos colchetes). Se eu usar esta regex, eu garanto que existe algum desses caracteres na string.

**Esta lista é apenas um exemplo, você deve adicionar os caracteres que precisar nela**. Vou usar a que eu defini acima, apenas para mostrar a ideia geral da regex, mas você deverá mudá-la para incluir todos os caracteres especiais que sua senha pode ter. Pode ser mais trabalhoso, mas pelo menos você garante que somente estes caracteres serão aceitos.

*Lembrando que os caracteres que têm [significado especial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) devem ser escapados com `\`. Por exemplo, se eu quiser que os colchetes sejam aceitos, tenho que fazer `[\[\]]` - o primeiro `[` delimita a classe de caracteres, e em seguida `\[` significa o próprio caractere `[`, `\]` significa o caractere `]` e por fim `]` fecha a classe de caracteres). Outra coisa é que dentro dos colchetes, nem todos precisam ser escapados (como o `$`, por exemplo) - uma maneira de testar é usar sites como o [regex101](https://regex101.com/) e escolher "javascript" no menu da esquerda, e ver se regex está correta.*

Pelo que entendi, suas senhas devem ter letras maiúsculas, minúsculas e números, e deve ter obrigatoriamente um caractere especial. Uma maneira de verificar é usando [*lookaheads*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), cuja sintaxe é `(?=expressão)`. No caso, queremos uma expressão que verifica se a string tem algum dos caracteres especiais, então bastaria usar `^(?=.*[@!#$%^&*()/\\])` - o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` significa "início da string", garantindo que vou verificar desde o início da senha. Em seguida, `.*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere", e em seguida temos a lista de caracteres especiais que eu defini.

Ou seja, o trecho `.*[@!#$%^&*()/\\]` verifica se há algum caractere especial na string. Se não houver nenhum, a expressão falha e a regex não retorna nenhum *match*. Se houver algum, a regex continua avaliando a string.

O truque do *lookahead* (`(?=...)`) é que ele verifica a expressão dentro dele, e se ela encontrar algum *match*, ele volta para onde estava e continua avaliando o restante da regex. No caso, ele está logo depois do `^`, então ele volta para o início da string.

Em seguida eu coloco tudo que a senha pode ter. Se ela pode ter os caracteres especiais, basta repeti-los. Se pode ter letras ou números, coloque tudo junto nos colchetes também: `[@!#$%^&*()/\\a-zA-Z0-9]`. Em seguida você pode colocar algum [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) para definir o tamanho da senha.

Por exemplo, `[@!#$%^&*()/\\a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20}` faz com que a regex aceite somente strings de 8 a 20 caracteres (e estes podem ser qualquer um que está nos colchetes: um caractere especial, uma letra ou número). Se quiser limitar apenas o tamanho mínimo, use `{8,}` (mínimo 8, máximo indeterminado). Ajuste para os valores que precisar.

Depois você coloca o marcador `$`, que significa "final da string". Assim você garante que do início ao fim, a string só tem o que está especificado na regex.

Então o nosso exemplo ficaria:

```js
let regex = /^(?=.*[@!#$%^&*()/\\])[@!#$%^&*()/\\a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20}$/;

// tem caracteres especiais
console.log(regex.test('a@4DFFd$fd')); // true

// tem caracteres especiais, mas tem menos de 8 caracteres
console.log(regex.test('a@4$f')); // false

// não tem caracteres especiais
console.log(regex.test('abcDE123456')); // false
```

Resumindo:

- o *lookahead* garante que há **pelo menos** um caractere especial (usando a lista predefinida que você pode ajustar para incluir os caracteres que desejar). Se for encontrado, ele volta para o início da string e avalia o restante da regex
- o restante garante que a string só terá os caracteres especiais, ou letras, ou números
- os marcadores de início e fim da string garantem que a string só tem os caracteres especificados (se você não usá-los, a string poderá ter caracteres que não fazem parte da regex e mesmo assim `test` retornará `true`).

A regex também vai aceitar strings como `$$$$$$$$$`, então cabe a você verificar se isso é aceitável, ou se vai incluir mais verificações.

---

Se quiser ter mais condições, como por exemplo "deve ter pelo menos uma letra e um dígito", basta adicionar mais *lookaheads*:

```js
let regex = /^(?=.*[@!#$%^&*()/\\])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[@!#$%^&*()/\\a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20}$/;

// tem pelo menos um caractere especial, uma letra e um número 
console.log(regex.test('a@4DFFd$fd')); // true
console.log(regex.test('abc123$ABC')); // true

// tem menos de 8 caracteres
console.log(regex.test('a@4$A')); // false

// tem caracteres especiais, mas não tem número
console.log(regex.test('abcDE$#fadfda')); // false
```

Cada *lookahead* (`(?=...)`) garante que a string tem pelo menos um caractere especificado. O primeiro tem a lista de caracteres especiais, o segundo tem um dígito (`[0-9]`) e o terceiro tem uma letra (`[a-zA-Z]`). Com isso, garanto que a string tem pelo menos um caractere de cada um destes tipos. Se quiser forçar que tenha pelo menos uma letra maiúscula e uma minúscula, basta separar o `[a-z]` e `[A-Z]`, fazendo um *lookahead* para cada.

E apenas para confirmar que esta regex não aceita emojis, caracteres japoneses, espaços, etc:

```js
let regex = /^(?=.*[@!#$%^&*()/\\])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[@!#$%^&*()/\\a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20}$/;

// concatenar as strings abaixo com esta, para ter pelo menos 8 caracteres
let s = "abc123$ABC";

// espaço (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm)
let space = " " + s;
console.log("senha: [" + space + "]");
console.log(regex.test(space)); // false

// TAB (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0009/index.htm)
let tab = "\t" + s;
console.log("senha: [" + tab + "]");
console.log(regex.test(tab)); // false

// caractere japonês (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/337B/index.htm)
let jp = "\u337b" + s;
console.log("senha: [" + jp + "]");
console.log(regex.test(jp)); // false

// emoji (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm)
let emoji = "\u{1F4A9}" + s;
// se a linha acima não funcionar (browsers mais antigos), troque por "\uD83D\uDCA9"
console.log("senha: [" + emoji + "]");
console.log(regex.test(emoji)); // false

// copyright (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a9/index.htm)
let cr = "\u00a9" + s;
console.log("senha: [" + cr + "]");
console.log(regex.test(cr)); // false
```

---

#### Sobre emojis

Especificamente sobre os emojis, não há problema em aceitá-los na sua senha, desde que seu código lide corretamente com isso.

Há muitas aplicações que já aceitam emojis em senhas, e até mesmo estudos dizendo que [isso as torna mais seguras e "divertidas"](http://www.spokesman.com/stories/2018/jul/16/why-emojis-might-be-your-next-password/). Claro que aí sua aplicação deve estar preparada para trabalhar corretamente com Unicode, coisa que [o JavaScript não é](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode). Basta ver os contadores de caracteres em campos de texto, por exemplo. Aqui mesmo no Stack Overflow, o campo de comentários considera que o emoji são 2 caracteres.

Antes de digitar o emoji:

[image: Campo de comentários dizendo que faltam 585 caracteres]

Depois de digitar o emoji:

[image: Após digitar um emoji, agora faltam 583 caracteres. O emoji foi contado como 2 caracteres]

Isso acontece basicamente por causa [disso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/443749/112052).

Mas felizmente eles são salvos e mostrados corretamente, então nesse caso específico, esse "problema" de tamanho é (na minha opinião) um problema menor. Isso é só para mostrar os problemas que você teria se usasse JavaScript para mostrar ao usuário que a senha não está com o tamanho aceito, por exemplo.

Se sua aplicação tem o mesmo problema (considera que [codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) acima de U+FFFF são 2 caracteres), verifique na documentação da sua linguagem como resolver.

De qualquer forma, este já é um assunto à parte (e você pode fazer outras perguntas sobre isso, se for o caso), mas é apenas para deixar claro que você pode sim usar emojis em senhas. O maior problema para senhas são os caracteres não imprimíveis e [alguns outros detalhes](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/17196) que temos que levar em conta ao permitir qualquer caractere Unicode.

Para aceitar emojis (e não aceitar caracteres de controle, espaços, etc), a regex fica um pouco mais complicada, como você pode ver [neste artigo](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode#astral-ranges) e [neste](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex) também. E vale notar também que [nem todo emoji equivale a apenas um codepoint](https://blog.emojipedia.org/emoji-zwj-sequences-three-letters-many-possibilities/)

Comment: Caramba, excelente resposta @hkotsubo! Sua resposta valeu muito mais do que as centenas de tutorias que achei na internet. Sou novo em JavaScript, por isso eu tinha essa dúvida quanto às regex, que é um tema considerado difícil até entre os programadores um pouco mais experientes nesta linguagem.

Comment: @EdinaldoRibeiro Obrigado! Pois é, regex é um assunto sem fim, e muito mais complexo do que parece (quanto mais estudo, mais percebo que eu não sabia nada). Dois sites que eu acho muito bons são [este](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) e [este](https://www.rexegg.com/), pois além de tutoriais, eles têm alguns casos práticos e explicam com detalhes como funciona, além de colocar diferenças entre as linguagens (pois é, não basta regex já ser difícil, ainda tem que saber como cada linguagem implementa)

Comment: Cada lookahead verifica uma condição. O primeiro verifica se tem algum caractere especial em algum lugar da string. O segundo verifica se tem algum dígito, e o terceiro verifica se tem alguma letra. É uma forma de obrigar a string a ter pelo menos um caractere especial, uma letra e um número. Sem o segundo e terceiro lookahead, a string poderia ter somente caracteres especiais, por exemplo.

Comment: Entendi. Após os três lookaheads há ainda a expressão `[@!#$%^&*()/\\a-zA-Z0-9]`. Qual seria a necessidade dela uma vez que a string já estaria validada pelos lookaheads?

Comment: O lookahead só verifica se existe algum caractere daquele tipo, e se encontrar, ele "pula" para o próximo trecho da regex (ele só serviu para verificar a existência daquele tipo de caractere, uma forma de obrigar a ter pelo menos um). A diferença é que `[@!#$%^&*()/\\a-zA-Z0-9]` não obriga nada (se tiver só letras ou só números, por exemplo, ela aceita). E além disso serve para eu colocar a quantidade `{8,20}` - eu não pus a quantidade no lookahead pq ele serve para verificar se existe pelo menos um. Embora pareça redundante, são propósitos diferentes

Comment: @EdinaldoRibeiro Atualizei a resposta com mais algumas informações. Eu não tinha colocado antes pq achei que ia desviar um pouco do assunto (pois aí teria que começar a falar dos detalhes do Unicode, etc), mas no fim achei importante colocar pelo menos alguns comentários a respeito

Comment: Cara, estava com alguma dificuldade de entender o RegExp, mas depois dessa explicação, consegui resolver uma questão importante aqui. Abraço e continue assim ^^

Answer (score 11):

O padrão `\W` selecionará todos os caracteres que **não forem alfanuméricos**, isto é, selecionará todos os caracteres exceto letras (A-Z), números (0-9) e *underline* (`_`).

Portanto, podemos montar um padrão. Assim:

```js
const pass1 = 'senhafraca';
const pass2 = '$3nh@f0rt3';

const regex = /\W|_/;

console.log(regex.test(pass1));
console.log(regex.test(pass2));
```

No padrão `/\W|_/`, temos:

- `\W`, que procura por caracteres não alfanuméricos;
- `|`, que é o mesmo que um "**ou**", nas expressões regulares.
- `_`, que procure todos os caracteres `_`, já que `\W` não seleciona caracteres underline.

[Fiz um exemplo no RegExr.](https://regexr.com/42scc)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua dica, Luiz.