# Lista para deleção lógica

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

Tenho uma dúvida sobre de quem é a responsabilidade (*back* ou *front*) pela tratativa de deleção lógica e no meu caso, tenho uma lista no *front* que é enviada para o *backend* gravar ou inativar o registro:

> `[{ idTabela: 2, codKit: "kitCopleto", dataInicio: "2019-01-01", dataFim: "2019-01-01"}, { idTabela: null, codKit: "kitCopleto2", dataInicio: "2019-01-01", dataFim: ""}]`

Atualmente quando o usuário exclui um item dessa lista, ao invés de setar o propriedade `DataFim` com a data de hoje, estamos excluindo fisicamente o item da lista e enviando para o *backend*.

Dessa forma o *backend* está sendo o responsável por realizar uma consulta no banco de dados, trazendo todos os itens e comparando com a lista que recebeu do *front*, se o item possui `IdTabela` logo ele já existe no banco de dados e deve ser alterado, caso contrario deve ser feito o `insert`.

Toda vez tenho que realizar um `select` na base trazendo todos os itens, isso não seria pouco performático?

Seria melhor trabalhar com 2 listas no *front* e enviar para o *backend* a lista já com a `dataFim` nos itens que foram excluídos pelo usuário?

Comment: Quando você excluir uma informação que é resgatada de um repositório qualquer o seu repositório precisa saber dessa exclusão ... após ele saber você envia para o  front que a lista não existe tal item ...

Comment: Ola Virgilio! Obrigado pela resposata, mas isso  só seria possivel se a cada item excluido fosse realizado um request...porém, por definição de UX foi determinado que só seria excluido de fato após o usuário clicar em "concluir"...dessa forma, sou obrigado a realizar um unico request enviando uma lista de itens.

Comment: Você só envia os itens excluídos, e após o retorno do backend remove do front !!!

Comment: Virgilio, o problema é um pouco maior. O usuário pode inserir novamente o mesmo item que excluiu ou inserir novos itens...logo, não posso encaminhar apenas os excluidos, devo encaminhar os novos registros tbm e estar sempre verificando se o item inserido já foi excluido, se o item ja estava cadastrado ou se trata-se de apenas um insert... Em algum lugar deve existir essa complexidade...minha dúvida é se o front seria o responsavel ou o backend.

OBS: Não preciso esperar o retorno do backend...conforme o usuario clica em excluir imediatamente o item some da lista.

Comment: Se o seu objetivo é quando grava pelo botão então se sabe resolver e já está fazendo assim, eu não faria assim eu faria cada um com sua responsabilidade, mas, pelo visto não pode... Então a regra é clara

Comment: @PauloBrunoSoaresSantos A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

> Toda vez tenho que realizar um `select` na base trazendo todos os itens, isso não seria pouco performático?

Sim, é menos performático.

> Seria melhor trabalhar com 2 listas no *front* e enviar para o *backend* a lista já com a `dataFim` nos itens que foram excluídos pelo usuário?

Não sei, só você pode responder, só você conhece todos detalhes do sistema. Pode falar alguma coisa sobre isto.

Você [confia em informação que vem do *front*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101)? Se sim, então seu software tem sérios problemas de segurança e provavelmente nem sabe. Dados só devem ser validados lá no *front* se não fizer diferença se de fato o dado é inválido e for algo que apenas ajuda o usuário trabalhar melhor, se for algo importante para a integridade do sistema não tem opção, só pode ser feito no *backend*.

Se há concorrência, qualquer comparação deve ser feita no momento que precisa e de forma exclusiva, caso contrário você entra em [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).