# É seguro deixar informações cruciais em um input hidden no HTML?

Tags: html, input, segurança

Posso deixar, por exemplo, o ID de um usuário q vou fazer `select` no `hidden`, e utilizá-lo (o id) sem precisar confirmar que aquele ID pertence ao usuário logado?
Em outras palavras, o usuário consegue alterar o `input hidden`?

Comment: Sim. No console tem como alterar e existe ferramenta de desenvolvedor no browser.

Comment: Até informações disabled ou read only?
Sempre soube dos texts

Comment: Não é seguro não. Pelo console faça `$("input[type=hidden]").each(function() {
     Console.log("Valor do hidden: " + $(this).val());
});` Que você pega os valores de todos os input hidden na página.

Comment: Qualquer informação do client pode ser alterada, o mais seguro é sempre validar no servidor: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/112052

Comment: Interessante. Quanto a validação, é melhor no front end ou back end? Nesse exemplo q dei, por ter q fazer query, terá q ser backend.
Contudo me fez pensar nessa situação:
Um formulário q precisa ser validado. O programador, antes de enviar o formulário, valida tudo no javascript, deixando todos os inputs validadinhos e coloca um código para submeter o formulário via javascript.
Se o usuário, malicioso, conseguir "pausar" o navegador logo depois da validação, re-alterar os inputs e "despausar" antes de submeter, teria um problema. Ou estou sonhando demais? É possível "pausar" o navegador?

Comment: Me responde uma coisa oque o cara vai fazer com um número?

Comment: A validação do JS é uma ajuda para evitar enviar informação que você sabe que está errada, e assim minimizar o peso no servidor. Mas ninguém lhe diz que não recebe informação errada mesmo com essa validação. Logo se quer ter a certeza que está certa tem que validar no servidor obrigatoriamente. Lembre-se que mesmo no browser eu posso desligar o javascript completamente e enviar as informações erradas. Posso inclusivamente abrir um programa para fazer pedidos http (como o Fiddler2 ou Postman) e fazer um pedido ao URI certo com dados que não façam sentido e quebrar a sua aplicação

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Tudo que está na máquina do cliente é manipulável. [Tudo o que você recebe de fora do seu servidor é inconfiável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101). Se seu servidor não estiver absolutamente seguro nem no seu código pode confiar (uma quantidade absurda de servidores está invadida por meses ou anos e as pessoas não sabem porque elas acham que é fácil mexer com isso e que a invasão será aparente, os bons invasores não deixam você perceber).

Se o seu sistema depende de qualidade da informação que vem de fora para funcionar ele está muito errado. Ninguém precisa sequer da sua página para enviar coisas inadequadas para seu servidor, e tudo o que ele puder pedir e você decidir entregar ele terá acesso.

A única coisa que o elemento `hidden` do formulário faz é não mostrar a informação na tela, mas ela está lá de forma extremamente livre, mas como dito acima, nem importa se é `hidden` ou não, basta você ter soltado a informação de alguma forma ela está disponível.

Sua visão está completamente equivocada, não precisa de um navegador para fazer nada disto. As invasões são feitas porque existem pessoas que entendem como funciona a tecnologia e outras tantas milhões que não entendem e deixam tudo vulnerável. As pessoas acham que podem fazer sites funcionais e seguros só escrevendo alguns códigos. A quantidade de conhecimento necessário é enorme e mais profunda que codificar algo.

O `id` é uma informação sigilosa? Duvido, mas se for, não pode passar isso para ninguém. Se o seu sistema depende do sigilo do `id` sua aplicação deve ter algo muito errada.

Se o seu sistema deixa pessoas externas fazer qualquer coisa que elas não deveriam só porque conhecem o `id` seu sistema está muito errado. Quem dá segurança ao seu sistema é você codificando de forma adequada e entendendo todos os tipos de ataques que podem ser feitos. Vai confirmar o que? Se não tiver um sistema de autenticação e autorização confiável, não tem o que confirmar.

Um exemplo, uns 80 ou 90% dos códigos que as pessoas postam aqui que tenham uma *query* sofrem de SQL Injection, nós (alguns de nós, outros nem ligam) ensinamos o certo e a pessoa continua fazendo errado. A maioria nem ouviu o termo que é só o tipo de ataque mais óbvio.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -1):

bom... se esse ID for considerado uma informação sigilosa, o correto é não manipular o mesmo através de elementos no HTML, já que pode ser encontrado ao tentar inspecionar a página. 
Se for um usuário mais experiente e que tem noção sobre as devTools do navegador, sim, ele conseguirá alterar o input hidden. O correto seria manipular essa informação por meio do servidor ou até mesmo do JavaScript, sem associar exatamente a um input do HTML. Outra solução seria colocar como parâmetro na url (se não for uma informação sigilosa, é claro).