# Por que são boas práticas a geração de código exclusivo de usuário?

Tags: modelagem, engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software, erp

Muitos sistemas corporativos usam um identificador exclusivo customizado. Você tem a geração do `id` no banco de dados e um código customizado. Quando uma busca pelo cliente é feita, o código customizado(algo como ZT2578B) é usando ao invés do id primary `key` da tabela.

Se existe o identificador exclusivo gerado pelo banco, por que devo ter um customizado?

Quais as boas práticas ou regras para gerar esse tipo de código?

Comment: A "boa prática" é usar quando tiver um motivo real para isso. Um exemplo entre várias razões para usar formatos customizados (só para fugir do que ja foi postado): placa de carro no Brasil, que é um "identificador único" eram letras + 4 digitos para que qualquer um conseguisse memorizar ao ver pra conseguir anotar depois. Nada impediria de ser uma numeração sequencial apenas, mas seria uma dor de cabeça danada controlar isso, além de perder a facilidade de memorização. Nota: pena que quem quis adotar essa loucura de placa do mercosul (cheia de problemas conceituais) não entende coisas básicas.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pra quem não tem experiência, esses códigos costumam ser classificatórios e cada caractere quer dizer alguma coisa específica, um agrupamento, uma forma de usar, é como se fossem *tags*. Pode parecer mas eles não são aleatórios, eles podem até expor informações sensíveis em alguns casos, por isso não servem para segurança.

> Se existe o identificador exclusivo gerado pelo banco, por que devo ter um customizado?

Isso teria que ser perguntado para quem fez, certo? Deve ser um requisito do sistema.

Pode ser que a vida toda esses códigos foram usados e não faria sentido mudar o que todo mundo está acostumado por causa do banco de dados.

Pode ser que o código usado aí tenha uma semântica específica que ajuda identificar o que é o item, então ele é melhor para as pessoas manipularem do que um `ID` sequencial do DB. Portanto é uma questão de UX.

Pode ser legislação ou regulamentação ou prática comum universal do setor.

Quase nunca é a segurança, não faz sentido ser, porque isso não dá segurança. Se alguém precisa se valer disso para ter segurança no sistema então tudo está perdido. Isso é chamado [segurança por obscuridade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46057/101) e é conhecido por ser problemático. Se tem outra medida de segurança fazer isso não muda nada, se não tem está inseguro. Se fizeram por isso, e só quem fez pode responder, trema de medo.

É muito fácil burlar o código montado e não sequencial depois de alguém ter visto alguns. Qualquer código não deve dar acesso inseguro de forma alguma. Todo sistema deve estar preparado para acesso normal seguro por formas não previstas no sistema e impedir o acesso inseguro. E note que o código é classificatório, não é um código longo e quase aleatório, como o UUID é (que [tem seus problemas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/401941/101), mas é outro assunto). Você precisa de um bom mecanismo de [autenticação e autorização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/399747/101) que controle a segurança, aí o código é irrelevante pra isso. Regra básica: [dados que vem de fora é inseguro por natureza](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101), isso inclui os códigos recebidos.

Se o código sequencial é sensível, este que tem uma qualificação pode ser mais sensível ainda e entregar uma informação relevante, não que isso importe.

Nem entrei na questão que talvez esse código seja só para aplicações internas, porque a pergunta não deixa claro isso. Mas não caia nessa de segurança em caso algum. Repito, é 99% certo que não é segurança, o 1% é uso errado de tentar dar segurança. Vulnerabilidade será achar que o código dá alguma segurança, o "invasor" sabe que não, e conta com essa ingenuidade de quem fez o sistema. Insegurança sempre ocorre por ignorância/ingenuidade do desenvolvedor.

Existe uma outra questão que pode se fazer: por que não usar esse código como chave primária?

Já respondi em [Valores que podem ser inseridos como chave primária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136398/101). Resumindo, esse código pode não ser estável, então não é bom candidato.

> Quais as boas práticas ou regras para gerar esse tipo de código?

Que bom perguntou o porquê. Pena que esse é um caso que só posso especular.

Boa prática é muleta para quem não quer aprender a motivação real. Entender o funcionamento daquilo em todos seus detalhes dá subsídios para tomar decisões corretas em vez de adotar algo que alguém já adotou para o caso dela, sem considerar o seu contexto, então cai nessa besteira. Boa prática pode ter sido criada porque não entende do assunto. Eu conheço um monte de coisa errada que fazem por aí sendo alegadas como boas práticas porque as pessoas não entendem o contexto, copiam sem avaliar a necessidade real. Pode ser até que era boa prática há décadas atrás, mas não faz mais sentido hoje, mas todo mundo continua fazendo.

Se pesquisar aqui sobre o uso de chave primária tem bastante informação ([eu mesmo respondi várias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101%20chave%20prim%C3%A1ria)) para entender o que pode ou não ser usado desta forma e porque a chave primária deve ser estável.

Agora, com relação ao código usado pela empresa para identificar o produto não é algo que deveria ser decidido pelo desenvolvedor, para essa pessoa o que vale é o `id` do banco de dados. Esse código secundário é para as pessoas adotarem, é para melhorar a experiência do usuário, e deve ser decidido pelas pessoas que estão envolvidas no processo de negócio, não é tecnologia. É comum em algumas organizações ter um comitê para decidir esses códigos de tão importante que ele é.

Só garanta que ele pode ser acessado facilmente, tenha um índice secundário para achar rápido.

Em geral quando tem esse tipo de código não deve ser exposto o `ID` da tabela, mas tem exceções.

Precisa ver se a criação dele deve ser validada de alguma forma, se houver um regra clara que possa ser confrontada com outros dados entrados.

Não estou dizendo que sei o que é melhor para esse caso, só dando alguma ideia para pensar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que o principal motivo é este: **segurança**.

E podemos citar aqui dois pontos sobre segurança: prevenir que uma vulnerabilidade seja explorada com mais facilidade e da segurança da informação em si.

## Usando a sequência para explorar uma falha

Comumente, usa-se identificadores sequenciais nas tabelas por meio de *identity* ou *sequence* (depende do seu banco de dados). Uma vantagem destes identificadores é que, por serem sequenciais, eles são mais legíveis aos usuários, pois só de olhar para eles você já consegue tirar uma noção da quantidade de registros na tabela, facilita ao fazer uma ordenação e ter (mais ou menos) a ordem que foram criados, etc.

Porém, por estes serem sequenciais, você consegue também adivinhar com facilidade o identificador do próximo registro. Isto pode ser considerada uma informação **sensível** quando você precisa identificar unicamente este registro em um sistema que quer expor estes dados externamente, pois expondo este identificador você estará fornecendo uma informação delicada (sensível) que pode ser usada em um possível ataque.

Ou seja, através de alguma **vulnerabilidade** do sistema o atacante pode explorar a falha sabendo todos os possíveis identificadores dos registros. Posso citar pelo menos [um caso no Brasil](https://economia.estadao.com.br/noticias/negocios,justica-condena-grupo-catho-por-roubo-de-dados,78486e) onde isto ocorreu.

Veja um exemplo de uma API fornecendo esta informação sensível:

```
GET /pedidos/105
```

Dá para entender pela requisição acima que estes registros de pedido podem ser identificados sequencialmente. Ou seja, provavelmente há o pedido com identificador 106, 107, 108, etc. Uma vulnerabilidade do sistema nesta parte, ou qualquer outra parte, poderia comprometer os dados dos pedidos.

Por esta razão, muitos sistemas optam por gerar identificadores únicos e não sequenciais, de modo que dificilmente um atacante conseguirá se aproveitar desta informação para tirar alguma conclusão a seu favor. Esta geração não precisa estar, necessariamente, no banco de dados, pois também pode ser gerada de forma independente por qualquer sistema (veja o [UUID](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%BAnico_universal), por exemplo).

Desta forma, a nossa mesma API ficaria:

```
GET /pedidos/123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
```

Mantendo o atacante impossibilitado de descobrir qualquer outro número possível de registro de pedido.

## Usando a sequência para extrair informações de negócio

Há também a segurança da informação em si, pois este identificador, sozinho, pode dizer muita coisa sobre os dados do sistema.

Por exemplo, um potencial competidor pode tirar várias conclusões com base nesta numeração sequencial. Ele pode analisar o volume de pedidos que você está gerando no decorrer dos dias e, com base apenas no identificador, saber qual o volume de pedidos que seu sistema está gerando.

## Código exclusivo ou identificador: qual usar?

A solução do identificador sequencial não exclui o uso de um "código exclusivo". Você pode ter ambos. Dependendo do código exclusivo e do volume dos dados que suas tabelas tem, é preferível manter o identificador sequencial por ter, provavelmente, [uma performance melhor](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/11/22/uuids-are-popular-but-bad-for-performance-lets-discuss/).

Comment: Caro @Dherik não quero discordar de sua resposta, mas UUID não tem foco segurança, a não ser que você esteja falando de segurança fora do nível aplicação, tipo apenas evitar da pessoa deduzir a quantidade de registros que seria a tal falha de segurança. UUID não é garantido como único, ele pode "falhar" e mesmo que este não fosse o caso. Na pratica mesmo um atacante poderia deduzir algumas coisas, ou até mesmo obter um ID de outro usuário só seria uma falha de segurança se algo no back-end estiver muito mal feito.

Comment: Veja bem, aqui no SOpt os IDs são todos expostos, isto nunca influenciou na segurança. Não estou discordando inteiramente da resposta, mas talvez o termo "segurança" e "vulnerabilidade" deveria ser usado com um pouco mais de "contexto", ou talvez simplesmente evitados, porque isto gera uma confusão de entendimento. Pode até ser que as pessoas pensem que aumenta a segurança usar um "código exclusivo", o Youtube gera urls assim, mas provavelmente nunca influenciou em nada. Pode ser um simples engano das pessoas, ou pode ser para "melhor" legibilidade.

Comment: `tipo apenas evitar da pessoa deduzir a quantidade de registros que seria a tal falha de segurança`, sim, esta é uma parte do meu ponto. A outra parte é que o atacante poderia explorar algum tipo de vulnerabilidade sabendo os identificadores dos pedidos. Corrigi minha resposta para deixar isto mais claro, estava confuso mesmo.

Comment: Que tipos de vulnarebilidade você pode explicar sabendo o meu ID aqui do SOpt? Aparece aqui na URL: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento, o valor é `3635`.

Comment: Digamos que suas informações fossem todas privadas. Se eu soubesse o seu ID e os IDs do SO fossem sequenciais, eu poderia aproveitar uma vulnerabilidade do SO (por exemplo, alguma rota que não exigisse autenticação) e pegar as informações privadas de todos os usuários. Isto, de fato, já aconteceu em um [episódio que ficou famoso](https://economia.estadao.com.br/noticias/negocios,justica-condena-grupo-catho-por-roubo-de-dados,78486e) no Brasil aproveitando-se do problema que citei acima.

Comment: Se entendi, sabendo que é sequencial (ou não), ainda teria que se valer de outro problema, que é mais grave, outras brechas existentes, é isso?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento exatamente!

Comment: Otimo, agora que entendi o que você desejava expressar vamos fazer vamos fazer um comparativo para entender os pontos do que se trata a segurança. Imagine que alguém roubasse meu login e senha FTP, pelo seus argumentos o equivalente em segurança de "código exclusivo" seria criar arquivos, scripts e pastas com nomes aleatórios para confundir quem já obteve o meu acesso ao FTP indevidamente. Mas me diga, embaralhar os nomes e afins trouxe alguma segurança de fato?

Comment: Certamente a questão não é segurança, ou quase certamente. Eu diria que tem 1% de chance de ser, mas aí é porque quem fez não tem ideia do que está fazendo. Difo isso inclusive porque esse tip ode código é basicamente sequencial, só não tão óbvio, mas fica óbvio olhando alguns poucos códigos. Este tip ode código é muito comum em certos tipos de atividade, ele não é aleatório e não pode ser confundido com algo parecido com um UUID. É uma opção, mas altamente improvável e se foi é erro, isso não dá segurança. Depois eu mudo minha resposta para falar nisso, mas nem vou me estender muito.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, no seu exemplo, não vejo vantagem, mas darei outro exemplo em cima do seu. Digamos que uma rede social tem perfis privados e as pessoas controlem o acesso a seu próprio álbum de fotos. As fotos em si são públicas mas você não sabe o link direto para elas. Porém, se você criar algum tipo de padrão "adivinhável" no nome das fotos, você pode acessar elas sem ter acesso ao álbum do usuário. O finado Orkut tinha este problema, depois corrigiram.

Comment: UUID por si só não traz nenhuma diferença na segurança. Tem uma confusão na resposta e nos comentários sobre o assunto. O caso do GET é nesse sentido, o problema não é ser sequencial, é o jeito que está usando. Você pode ter um ID sequencial sem problema nenhum, e não mostrar ele nunca para o público.

Comment: Mas neste ultimo a solução nem seria "código exclusivo", foi erro total da maneira que armazenaram, o facebook também teve isto, se eu não me engano, a estratégia de armazenamento é que estava toda errada, colocar "código exclusivo" não necessariamente resolveria, tanto que as "soluções" aplicadas nessas mídias sociais foi ajustar o armazenamento e não criar códigos de exclusividade, mas acho que estão ai os pontos que eu quis dizer, pode parecer que uma coisa resolve, quando na verdade é tipo uma parede de madeirite pintado para parecer um muro de concreto.

Comment: @Bacco, não falei que um substitui o outro, apenas expliquei o motivo de um "código exclusivo" existir. `Você pode ter um ID sequencial sem problema nenhum, e não mostrar ele nunca para o público. Se tem problema ele ser sequencial, mostre outra coisa no URL que leve ao ID desejado.`. Isto casa com o que expliquei acima.

Comment: Não sei se ficou claro que isso não dá segurança. Mas eu acho que a pergunta não foi entendida por muita gente, por isso até acrescentei uma introdução na minha resposta. A pergunta é sobre o que fez alguém adotar isso. A pergunta não é muito boa porque só quem fez o sistema pode responder. Uma especulação possível é a segurança, mas uma péssima, só adotada por erro, Não foi dito, deu margem para especular, mas nada indica que o sistema é web e acessado externamente, e muito menos implica em UUID, que é outra coisa, misturou muito as coisas.Como algumas pessoas gostaram da resposta me preocupa

Comment: porque significa que elas acreditam que isso dá segurança mesmo. Quem quer "invadir", invadirá mesmo fazendo isso, se tiver outro problema que permite isso, isso é como colocar um band aid em um furo de um tiro tomado. O mais importante que o código é simples demais para ser algo usado para "aumentar a segurança". Ele não é aleatório que ajudaria um pouco dificultar certos padrões, mas não aumentar a segurança que é uma palavra forte demais para que o que poderia acontecer se usasse um código aleatório.

Comment: @Maniero das poucas vezes que vi um código exclusivo usado em uma tabela, normalmente foi para expor algo para fora, então achei importante citar. Sobre o UUID, eu citei o UUID como um exemplo, existem outras alternativas. Os casos que citei acima (Orkut e Catho) foram exemplos do aproveitamento de uma vulnerabilidade com base neste sequencial que poderiam ter sido evitados ou dificultados caso fosse usado um identificador não sequencial.

Comment: @Dherik então você precisa ver outras coisas, quase todas as coisas que eu vi não era isso. Bom, eu não trabalho com startups e eu acho que não trabalhou com muitas empresas "normais" que usam isso. É extremamente comum. O caso que você citou não teria sido evitado porque os dados eram públicos para todos que possuem conta nesses sites. Não houve quebra de segurança alguma, podia ter o código que fosse e tudo seria capturado. Poderia ter dado um trabalho ligeiramente maior pra fazer um *script*, e olhe lá, talvez já tivesse algo que dificultasse e não impediu. Você está inferindo que não tinha

Comment: @Maniero então acredito que você também precisa ver outras coisas. Eu não trabalho com startups (não sei se entendi esta parte, mas tudo bem), então acredito que foram todas empresas "normais". Sobre evitar ou dificultar, isto pode variar dependendo da vulnerabilidade apresentada e do número de informações que o atacante terá (ou que forneceu a ele). Quanto menos informações você fornecer menos chances você dará para alguém explorar uma falha de segurança no seu sistema.

Comment: Esse tema de "segurança por obscuridade" já foi desmistificado faz muito tempo, recomendo uma pesquisa quem tiver interesse na discussão, assim cada um tira suas conclusões. É assunto mais do que batido. No caso específico foram dados acho que **dois** exemplos onde o id unico supostamente ajudaria (baseado em suposição de que naquele cenário e bug bem específico, escolhido a dedo, a "não sequencialidade" ajudaria algo, como se ninguém pudesse fazer um script que tentasse valores diversos) e esquecidos os outros milhares de casos onde é sequencial e não dá problema nenhum e nem nunca vai dar.

Comment: @Dherik eu vejo outras coisas, vejo coisas terríveis sendo feitas por gente inexperiente que faqz coisas que startups fazem mesmo fora de startups, porque é o que está na moda, e elas seguem o que startup fala que é bom. Eu tenho experiência tendo desenvolvido ERP atendendo milhares de empresas (quase todas grandes, algumas médias), quase todas usam códigos como o citado na pergunta, e **nenhuma** é por segurança, é por organização interna ou do setor. O que eu acho ruim é as pessoas acharem que isso dá alguma segurança, é justamente por isso que há inseguranças "se tirar antes não engravida".

Comment: @Bacco, estou ciente do termo de segurança por obscuridade, é um assunto que abrange muita coisa. Só acho que não se aplica no caso.

Comment: @Maniero, nunca trabalhei com ERP, mas já trabalhei com produtos internos de grandes empresas também (não que isto ou aquilo seja um argumento forte). Claro que só o uso do "código externo" não trará segurança para a aplicação, mas acredito que este ponto já esteja claro nos comentários e na minha resposta.

Comment: @Dherik me desculpe, mas o problema da sua resposta pode ser resumido justamente nesse último comentário para o Bacco, isso é exatamente a segurança por obscuridade, sem nenhuma nuance diferente. E no seu último comentário você diz que não é mais sobre segurança, não está claro na sua resposta. Ela diz na primeira linha que o **principal** motivo (não é nem secundário, pontual) é a segurança. Diz depois que não, mas aí desmente o motivo da resposta, e sem isso ela não tem razão para existir. Enfim, já perdi tempo demais. Pelo menos quem se der ao trabalho de ler tudo verá que isso é um erro.

Comment: @Maniero, `sem nenhuma nuance diferente` isto também discutível. No segundo parágrafo da minha resposta está lá o motivo que coloquei *segurança*. Para mim vocês entenderam o que eu quis dizer, não é questão de contradição, só não concordam (o que é perfeitamente saudável). Concordo que também já perdemos tempo, a conversa já está andando em círculos.