# Criptografia de senha em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, post, segurança, criptografia

Possuo esse trecho de código que realiza o envio de usuário e senha para meu webService feito em Asp C#.

```
function validation(){


     var json =({ "emailUser": email, "passwordUser": passWord });
    console.log(json); 

    xhr.open("POST", "https://domain/api/compare", true);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(json);

    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        var response1 = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    }
}
```

Como poderia ser feito a criptografai da senha antes do envio ?
O que eu poderia utilizar para fazer essa criptografia ?

Comment: http://stunnix.com/prod/jo/ Dê uma olhada nesse site

Comment: http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/

Comment: tem certeza que precisa disto? O tráfego já não é criptografado? Quer algo que não sabemos?

Comment: Essas coisa deve ser colocada no servidor e não no cliente...

Comment: Fala @Maniero tudo bém ? Entendo, mas é correto eu deixar a senha salva no banco sem nenhuma criptografia  ? estou tentando criptografar a senha para comparação no WebService com a senha que está salva no banco, assim fazendo a validação de usuário.

Comment: Criptografa lá, e do jeito certo. Quem garante que no cliente a senha será criptografada do jeito que você espera? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101. Está cometendo o mesmo erro que isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101

Comment: Obrigado, consegui clarear mais as idéias

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez que você está no navegador, você pode utilizar o PBKDF2. A resposta do @Dr.Helsing é completamente inútil para a finalidade de "proteger a senha".

O PBKDF2 é suportado pelo WebCrypto, em qualquer navegador moderno.

---

Em geral seria algo como:

```
// Essa informação é a senha, que deve vim de um `<input>` por exemplo:
let password = new TextEncoder().encode("password");

// Essa informação deve vim do banco de dados (ou derivado de outra entrada constante, que não seja a própria senha), isto deve ser única por usuário/senha:
let salt = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]).buffer; 

// Essa informação é a dificuldade da derivação:
let iterations = 500000;
let algo = "SHA-512";


key = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw",
    password,
    "PBKDF2",
    false,
    ["deriveBits", "deriveKey"]
);

pbkdf2 = await  window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
    {"name":"PBKDF2", "salt": salt, "iterations": iterations, "hash": algo},
    key,
    {"name": "AES-CBC", "length": 256}, // Isso aqui é confusão do WebCrypto. Isso daqui é só para definir o tamanho final para 32bytes!
    true,
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"],
);

// Aqui você tem o resultado, a senha derivada:
result = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
    "raw",
    pbkdf2,
);
```

Dessa forma, o seu servidor só terá acesso ao resultado da derivação, mas nunca terá acesso à senha em texto-claro. Isso parece ser o que você busca.

Entretanto, como mencionado nos comentários, você ainda deve derivar novamente em seu servidor. Então basicamente a construção final seria:

1. Usuário digita "seuemail@provedor.com"
2. A) O algoritmo utiliza o e-mail (ou um `HASH(seuemail)`) como `salt`.
   B) O servidor responde o `salt` baseado no e-mail digitado (consulta o banco de dados.
3. O usuário deriva a senha usando PBKDF2 (código acima).
4. O usuário envia a senha derivada (o `result`) para o servidor.
5. O servidor efetua uma nova derivação (por exemplo, `Argon2(senha_do_passo_4)`).
6. O servidor verifica a senha gerada, no passo 5, contra a informação que possui no servidor.

---

Existe alguns detalhes que deve levar em consideração:

1. Você não deve armazenar o resultado (o `result` ou a pre-imagem da segunda derivação) como texto-claro num banco de dados (ou qualquer outra midia).
2. Você não deve reutilizar o salt para múltiplos usuários.
3. Você DEVE utilizar TLS/SSL na comunicação (isto é até uma exigência para o WebCrypto em alguns navegadores).

---

Algumas coisas que pode chamar a atenção, como o fato de "enviar o salt para o usuário".

Isso não é um problema. Deve considerar que a única forma de saber se a senha é correta é requisitando o servidor (não há como fazer isso offline. Por consequência, fazer um brute-force de `PBKDF2(senha, salt)` ou de `senha` é no mínimo igual (sendo que PBKDF2 possui um custo computacional maior) e medidas contra a busca exaustiva são igualmente aplicada aos dois casos. Ou seja, revelar o `salt` a partir do e-mail não implica em qualquer problema diferente do que se utilizar o método de login "tradicional".

---

Você também pode encriptar a senha utilizando AES/Salsa20/ChaCha20, alguns serviços recentemente passaram a fazer isso (como Facebook, TikTok *e acho qu e o YouTube também*). *O Facebook utiliza o LibSodium, que utiliza o Salsa20.*

Não estou certo ainda do motivo que fazem isso, assumindo que já utilizam TLS/SSL, mas.... fazem. Você também pode fazer isso, mas tenha em mente que deve derivar/fazer a hash da senha novamente no lado do servidor, de qualquer forma.

Answer (score -8):

usa o "atob" do javascript

```
var senha = "123";
var segredo = btoa(senha);
var revelado = atob(segredo);

console.log("segredo: " + segredo);
console.log("revelado: " + revelado);
```