# Não preciso preocupar com o frontend?

Tags: node.js, angular, vue.js, front-end, segurança

Eu precisaria me preocupar com a vulnerabilidade do *frontend* ou apenas com o *backend*?

Comment: Oi mineiro, sim, a sua resposta foi útil para mim, obrigado!

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Não é que não precisa se preocupar, só que você nunca poderá garantir segurança do seu código porque ele pode até mesmo ser jogado de lado e se comunicar com o *backend* sem ele, então qualquer coisa que faça ali pode ser burlado se a pessoa quiser, por isso [o maior controle deve ser no servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101).

O que não quer dizer que não deva fazer códigos adequados no cliente para evitar uma interceptação no meio do caminho, quando tanto o servidor quanto o cliente querem trabalhar direito e tem algo no meio que não quer, por isso é importante a criptografia, manter controles de comunicação e autenticação se for o caso.

Também importa fazer um código para dar uma melhor experiência ao usuário, mas não que isso seja por causa da segurança.

Também pode ser útil manter alguma proteção para evitar um ataque ingênuo, mas não por segurança mesmo, não considere isso como medida eficaz. Lembre-se que tudo que está em um computador que você não tem controle não pode confiar sequer no que está executando. E no computador que pode confiar, normalmente o servidor, é confiável até ele ser invadido.

Answer (score -1):

Eu sugiro que você faça validações tanto no backend quanto no frontend. A validação feita no frondend evita que mensagens de erro que o usuário não entenda apareçam para ele e a validação feita no backend impede que usuários espertinhos burlem o sistema, utilizando ferramentas de desenvolvedor do próprio navegador.